# Does uninstalling a package with "pip" also remove the dependent packages?

Tags: python, package, pip

When you use `pip` to install a package, all the required packages will also be installed with it (dependencies). Does uninstalling that package also remove the dependent packages?

Comment: I have found in [pip newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/python-virtualenv/JqIbyUDy2-E/discussion) that pip people don't want this functionality, at least for now. What a pitty!

Comment: I don't really want to implement it because it's so much process but I guess you can `pip freeze` before and after and then do some sort of `diff` to isolate only new ones and then specifically `pip uninstall -r` those ones as well as the original top level in `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

No, it doesn't uninstall the dependencies packages. It only removes the specified package:

```
$ pip install specloud
$ pip freeze # all the packages here are dependencies of specloud package
```

> figleaf==0.6.1
> nose==1.1.2
> pinocchio==0.3
> specloud==0.4.5

```
$ pip uninstall specloud
$ pip freeze
```

> figleaf==0.6.1
> nose==1.1.2
> pinocchio==0.3

As you can see those packages are dependencies from `specloud` and they're still there, but not the `specloud` package itself.

As mentioned below, you can install and use the [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove) utility to remove a package plus unused dependencies.

Comment: What about exclusive dependency packages of `specloud` package?

Comment: @Fusion Those packages are the specloud's dependency.

Comment: Rephrasing @Fusion 's question what if you already have another package installed already (and that package has it's own dependencies) you will not be able to differentiate which dependencies belong to which package. This approach only works if you have a clean initial (virtual) environment.

Comment: @Bengineer thank you for your reply. What if I have already removed the parent package? ... and only then realized I have unused dependencies. Do I need to reinstall the parent for ```pip-autoremove``` to delete the dependencies?

Answer (score 407):

You can install and use the [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove) utility to remove a package plus unused dependencies.

```
# install pip-autoremove
pip install pip-autoremove
# remove "somepackage" plus its dependencies:
pip-autoremove somepackage -y
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has no real Python3 support, yet (see https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove/issues/18) .

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus - I'm on python 3.8.3 and I tested and still see the command executed as `pip-autoremove` (dash not underscore).  `pip_autoremove` gives me `command not found`.

Comment: @bwv549 I have to explain that I executed it via `python<version>` (when version has to be specified). In that way, we need to adapt the name to `pip_autoremove` (dash is not allowed as package name). For example `python3.8 pip_autoremove` works but `python3.8 pip-autoremove` does not. Otherwise, as you pointed out, as simple terminal command `pip-autoremove`, it works perfectly :) —though just the default python version of the system is used. Thanks for your message.

Comment: In a virtualenv, the pip-autoremove blindly removes sibling dependencies listed in your requirements.txt. For example, `requests==2.22.0` was listed as a requirement but was removed as a result of being a sub-dependency of another package anyway.

Comment: `pip-autoremove` doesn't working for me: `The 'pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3"' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: Within my activated Python 3.6 environment I had to use `pip_autoremove somepackage -y` in order to remove 'somepackage'.

Comment: did not work on windows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip_autoremove'`  (https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove/issues/43)

Comment: [pip3-autoremove](https://github.com/enjoysoftware/pip3-autoremove) worked for me. I'm on Windows 10 using Python 3.8.3. Running `pip3-autoremove jupyterlab -y` deleted jupyterlab including its dependencies.

Comment: `pip-autoremove` has been in a broken state for a year because its devs don't maintain it properly. In order to repair it ([source](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove/pull/44#issuecomment-1042448589)) you have to find the file `pip_autoremove.py` which is in your python install directory at `<python_root>/Scripts/` and move it to `<python_root>/Lib/site-packages`, then it will work normally. @TomoyukiAota Do NOT use `pip3-autoremove`, a project that hasn't been updated for two years and has so few stars if you don't want to mess up or compromise your system.

Answer (score 17):

I've successfully removed dependencies of a package using this bash line:

```
for dep in $(pip show somepackage | grep Requires | sed 's/Requires: //g; s/,//g') ; do pip uninstall -y $dep ; done
```

this worked on pip 1.5.4

Comment: Although technically this solution *does* successfully remove all the dependencies, as mentioned in the other answers, it *also* uninstalls dependencies which are **not unique to the target**, including ones installed from system packages. For example, on my system this script eventually failed because the target package had dependencies in common with pip, so pip uninstalled its own dependencies before the script could finish, and then failed.

Comment: Beware this removes **only** the next level down dependencies, but **not** the dependencies of those dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution even though it might be a little difficult for some to carry out.

1st step (for python3 and linux):

```
pip3 install pip-autoremove
```

2nd step:

```
cd /home/usernamegoeshere/.local/bin/
```

3rd step:

```
gedit /home/usernamegoeshere/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py
```

and change all pip(s) to pip3
4th step:

```
./pip-autoremove packagenamegoeshere
```

At least, this was what worked for me ...

Comment: This worked for me without the edits as the pip available (Fedora 36) is `pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)`

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try for https://github.com/cls1991/pef.
It will remove package with its all dependencies.

Comment: pef only seems to work in virtual environments, unfortunately.

Comment: It's just in safety considerations, you are able to hack the code,  simply switch off the protection code.

Comment: Does it make sure that those dependencies are "dangling" i.e. unneeded by other distributions?

Comment: Yeah, it's based on reference counting.

Comment: hey guys I have forked and modified the code. Please find the link below.  
https://github.com/nalangekrushna/pef

Comment: mine doesn't even work in the virtual environment .-.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a `venv` environment in linux, you can use:
`pip uninstall $(pip freeze) -y`, it worked like a charm here.

It will list all dependencies installed and will iterate through the list and confirm uninstall with `-y` parameter

Answer (score 1):

I just found a fastest way to do it

```
pip uninstall -y (pip freeze)
```

It will delete all the dependencies

If you want to make sure you won't uninstall the one that is important to you

you can try this one

```
pip freeze > ./python_uninstall_modules.txt
pip uninstall -r python_uninstall_modules.txt -y
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple pipx.x uninstall module_name worked for me on RHEL7 to uninstall a Python package. Yes, it removed all the dependencies as well.

ex:      pip3.6 uninstall pandas

Answer (score 0):

To delete the dependencies of a specific package in your project:

1.In a new folder(outside of your project) create a new venv:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

2.Activate your new venv and in it only install the package you are trying to uninstall the dependencies of:

```
pip install YOUR-SPECIFIC-PACKAGE
```

3.Pip freeze your packages and name them something like uninstall-dependencies.txt:

```
pip freeze --> uninstall-dependencies.txt
```

4.Copy "uninstall-dependencies.txt" list to the virtual environment you are trying to remove the specific package including all its dependencies from.

5.Navigate back to your initial project (activate its environment if not already active) and use your new list as a guide to remove everything linked to the package you are uninstalling:

```
pip uninstall -y -r uninstall-dependencies.txt
```

*The "-y" command performs the uninstall without asking you to confirm the removal of every single dependency*

6.Test your project if everything is the way you want it to be.

7.Don't forget to pip freeze now that you have removed the package and its dependencies:

```
pip freeze -r requirements.txt
```

This should delete the specific package and its dependencies while keeping other packages in your project.
Of course, there is also a possibility you have multiple packages with the same dependencies, in which case you could reinstall your new requirements.txt to set them up again.

Maybe a bit hacky but did the trick for me.

Comment: This is functionally the same as Fábio Correia's answer, just broken down into more steps.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for your comment. I am failing to see how Fábio Correia's answer is the same as mine.  
Fabios answer is basically "pip uninstall -y -r requirements.txt". My answer Picks a specific module from requirements.txt that came with additional dependencies and ONLY deletes that module + the dependencies that came with it. As far as I see that was what Hossein was asking for initially? 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem came from the fact that I had created a `pip` alias in my `~/.zshrc` file (it could be ~/.bash_profile, if you're using bash). Since my profile had `alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3`, it used this installation whether I was in or out of an environment.

You can check this using `which pip` in your `conda` enviroment. If it still points to `/usr/bin/pip3`, then it's using your User/ directory.

As a note, after you unalias `pip`, and then install a package with `pip`, you may still get a message that it's using a cached version. This is okay. You can user `conda list` within the environment to confirm that the package was indeed installed in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a package with its dependencies try this simple Python script:

```
# pip-uninstall-with-dependencies.py

from sys import argv
from pip._internal.commands.show import search_packages_info
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
from typing import List, Dict

if len(argv) < 2:
    print(f"Usage: {argv[0]} pkg1 [pkg2 ...]")
    exit(1)

def get_dependency_tree(packages: List[str], candidates: Dict[str, List[str]] = dict()) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    for package in packages:
        if not candidates.get(package):
            pkg_info = next(search_packages_info([package]))
            candidates[package] = pkg_info.required_by
            for package in pkg_info.requires:
                get_dependency_tree([package])

    return candidates

candidates = get_dependency_tree(argv[1:])

# eliminate required
for package in list(candidates):
    diff = set(candidates[package]).difference(list(candidates))
    if diff:
        print(f"Package {package} cannot be removed, it is required by {diff}")
        del candidates[package]

print("Uninstalling packages and dependencies:", *candidates)
for package in candidates:
    main(['uninstall', '-y', package])
```

How to use:

```
pip-uninstall-with-dependencies.py crypto
```

NOTE: If you are concerned about removing too many packages, just remove '-y' option in the main() call.