# Python / Pandas - GUI for viewing a DataFrame or Matrix

Tags: python, user-interface, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the Pandas package and it creates a DataFrame object, which is basically a labeled matrix. Often I have columns that have long string fields, or dataframes with many columns, so the simple print command doesn't work well. I've written some text output functions, but they aren't great.

What I'd really love is a simple GUI that lets me interact with a dataframe / matrix / table. Just like you would find in a SQL tool. Basically a window that has a read-only spreadsheet like view into the data. I can expand columns, page up and down through long tables, etc.

I would suspect something like this exists, but I must be Googling with the wrong terms. It would be great if it is pandas specific, but I would guess I could use any matrix-accepting tool. (BTW - I'm on Windows.)

Any pointers?

Or, conversely, if someone knows this space well and knows this probably doesn't exist, any suggestions on if there is a simple GUI framework / widget I could use to roll my own? (But since my needs are limited, I'm reluctant to have to learn a big GUI framework and do a bunch of coding for this one piece.)

Comment: Would Pyspread be of any assistance?

Comment: Looks like overkill for my need, but I'll look into it if there's nothing easier. Thanks.

Comment: can this be done in spyder(http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/)? I have been using Rstudio with R and I like being able to see the data with a single click. I totally agree that a comparable tool for Python/Pandas is missing and iPython is great but not in this area.

Comment: i've found that the ipython notebook is pretty good for this.

Comment: If you want to view your full data frame in a new browser window, instead of in a limited output cell, you could use the simple python+javascript solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554839/pop-out-expand-jupyter-cell-to-new-browser-window/40855214#40855214

Comment: Anybody have a suggestion for eclipse? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164678/viewing-pandas-df-in-eclipse-on-a-separate-window

Comment: (2020). There is [D-tale](http://alphatechadmin.pythonanywhere.com/dtale/main/1). For Jupyter, [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/two-essential-pandas-add-ons-499c1c9b65de) presents two powerful add-ons: [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) and [pivottablejs](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs)

Comment: You can use Pandas GUI. My answer can be of help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283412/5114585

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use `QTableWidget` from PyQt to display a `DataFrame`. I create a `QTableWidgetObject` and then populate with `QTableWidgetItems` created with `DataFrame` values.
Following is the snippet of code that reads a CSV file ,create a `DataFrame`, then display in a GUI:

```
df  = read_csv(filename, index_col = 0,header = 0)
self.datatable = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent=self)
self.datatable.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
self.datatable.setRowCount(len(df.index))
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        self.datatable.setItem(i,j,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iget_value(i, j))))
```

**Update:**

As this answer was quite old, it deserves an update. There are many options available now to view the dataframes in GUI.

1. As others have pointed out, Python IDEs such as Spyder
   come with dataframe viewers.
2. [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) is
   another option for the jupyter notebook widget that renders the dataframes within the notebook.

If someone still wants to code a simple GUI to view the dataframes within Jupyter, following is the complete , minimal example using Pyqt5 .

```
%gui qt5 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QScrollArea, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout,QTableWidgetItem
import pandas as pd

win = QWidget()
scroll = QScrollArea()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
table = QTableWidget()
scroll.setWidget(table)
layout.addWidget(table)
win.setLayout(layout)    


df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [4 ,5, 6],"b" : [7, 8, 9],"c" : [10, 11, 12]},index = [1, 2, 3])
table.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
table.setRowCount(len(df.index))
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        table.setItem(i,j,QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iloc[i, j])))

win.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what is the `self` in the snippet?

Comment: It refers to the  object  of the class that extends the user interface class such as QWidget or QMainWindow

Answer (score 58):

**2019 update:** I'm currently working on a successor [tabloo](https://github.com/bluenote10/tabloo).

---

I wasn't fully satisfied with some other GUIs, so I created my own, which I'm now maintaining [on Github](https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI). Example:

[image]

Apart from the basic table + plot functionality, I wanted to have a specific way to filter data:

- select a column to filter from a combo box
- write an "underscore expression" to filter on that column using arbitrary Python code. For example: `_ > 0` to filter positive values only, or more complex expressions like `(_ >= date(2016, 1, 1)) & (_ <= date(2016, 1, 31))` e.g. for datetime columns.

Comment: Gui is showing numbers - it shows empty columns instead of numbers.

Comment: @javed: Could you please use the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI/issues) and clarify what you mean?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and seems there is some trouble when I want to install your package and dependencies, do I need a python 3.x environment to install your package?

Comment: @cloudscomputes It has been developed under/for Python 2.7, so this shouldn't be the issue. But same comment as above: This is not the right place to give support. Please use the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI/issues).

Answer (score 19):

The question was post in 2012 and other answers may be too old to apply.

The answer in 2016 is, we should use Pycharm and it's shipped with `DataFrame` viewer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the case when you are not using the debug mode?

Comment: Doesnt work when debug mode is not used. But in spyder we can view without debug mode.

Comment: @uday You can still browse dataframe without debug mode.  I can confirm that Pycharm has the fastest and smooth dataframe gui, though it is not without problem.

Comment: Ideally, python user should not have to change the IDE just to view some dataframe content.

Answer (score 12):

Pandas 0.13 provides as an experimental feature:

PySide support for the qtpandas `DataFrameModel` and `DataFrameWidget`

see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/doc/source/faq.rst

you can add this feature using

```
from pandas.sandbox.qtpandas import DataFrameModel, DataFrameWidget
```

Comment: Thank you for this! There's now a working sample in the Pandas docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/faq.html#visualizing-data-in-qt-applications

Answer (score 10):

In addition to all the valuable answers, I would like to mention that the Spyder IDE (https://github.com/spyder-ide) has this feature as you can see in my printscreen below:

[image]

This is just an objective fact and not advertisement for any IDE :) I don't want to trigger any debate on this question.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the to_html() dataframe method to convert the dataframe to html and display it in your browser. Here is an example assuming you have a dataframe called df. You should check the documentation to see what other options are available in the to_html() method.

```
# Format floating point numbers with 2 decimal places.
data_table = df.to_html(float_format=lambda x: '%6.2f' % x,
    classes="table display")
# The to_html() method forces a html table border of 1 pixel.
# I use 0  in my table so I  change the html, since there is no 
# border argument in the to_html() method.
data_table = data_table.replace('border="1"','border="0"')
# I alson like to display blanks instead on nan.
data_table = data_table.replace('nan', '')
```

If you want to get the table to be nicely formatted and scrollable then you can use the datatables plug-in for jQuery [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/). Here is the javascript I use to display a table the scrolls in both x and y directiions.

```
$('.table').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "sScrollY": 900,
    "sScrollX": 1000,
    "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, -1], [50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The dataframe's to_clipboard() method can be used to quickly copy, and then paste the dataframe into a spreadsheet:

```
df.to_clipboard()
```

Comment: once I run this command, my kernel crushed

Comment: Note that your solution doesn't work in a cloud-based environment such as [GoogleColab](https://colab.research.google.com/) [ref1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/412721) [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58687491/10452700), so such _copy pastable_ solution like [Pyperclip](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#welcome-to-pyperclip-s-documentation) module has been not a case except for non-VM local machines to reproduce the data.

Answer (score 6):

There's [tkintertable](https://code.google.com/p/tkintertable/) for python2.7 and [pandastable](https://code.google.com/p/pandastable/wiki/Usage) for python3.

Comment: `pandastable` is awesome and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

The nicest solution I've found is using `qgrid` (see [here](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid), and also mentioned in the [pandas docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/ecosystem.html)). You can install by

```
pip install qgrid
```

and then you need to do a further install (just once) in your `IPython` notebook

```
qgrid.nbinstall()
```

Afterwards, it's as easy as taking your `pandas` `df` and running

```
qgrid.show_grid(df)
```

The other nice thing is that it renders in `nbviewer` too. See it in action [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/quantopian/qgrid/blob/master/qgrid_demo.ipynb)

Comment: I installed qgrid and found that it also installs a large number of dependencies. For removal, I had to use pip-autoremove utility `pip install pip-autoremove` and `pip-autoremove qgrid -y` to remove it with unused dependencies (as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915998/does-uninstalling-a-package-with-pip-also-remove-the-dependent-packages).

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is no easy solution. So, below is a little function to open a dataframe in Excel. It's probably not production quality code, but it works for me!

```
def open_in_excel(df, index=True, excel_path="excel.exe", tmp_path='.'):
    """Open dataframe df in excel.

    excel_path - path to your copy of excel
    index=True - export the index of the dataframe as the first columns
    tmp_path    - directory to save the file in


    This creates a temporary file name, exports the dataframe to a csv of that file name,
    and then tells excel to open the file (in read only mode). (It uses df.to_csv instead
    of to_excel because if you don't have excel, you still get the csv.)

    Note - this does NOT delete the file when you exit. 
    """

    f=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=tmp_path, suffix='.csv', prefix='tmp_')
    tmp_name=f.name
    f.close()

    df.to_csv(tmp_name, index=index)
    cmd=[excel_path, '/r', '/e', tmp_name]
    try:
        ret_val=subprocess.Popen(cmd).pid
    except:
        print "open_in_excel(): failed to open excel"
        print "filename = ", tmp_name
        print "command line = ", cmd
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

    return
```

Comment: Brilliant, works nicely! To get it working in Python 3: `import tempfile`, `import subprocess`, `import sys`, update path for `excel.exe` to something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Excel.exe` (depending on ones system). The `print` statements need brackets around them to make them compatible with Python 3. Can also use `.to_excel` after `pip install xlwt`, which writes to `.xls` rather than `.csv` for the temporary file.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on a PyQt GUI for pandas DataFrame you might find useful.  It includes copying, filtering, and sorting.

https://gist.github.com/jsexauer/f2bb0cc876828b54f2ed

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you use **QTableView** not **QTableWidget**. **QTableView** is based on model-view programming.

> There are 2 different ways how these widgets can access their data. The traditional way involves widgets which include internal containers for storing data. This approach is very intuitive, however, in many non-trivial applications, it leads to data synchronization issues. The second approach is model/view programming, in which widgets do not maintain internal data containers

I wrote a model for **pandas dataframe**.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Class to populate a table view with a pandas dataframe
    """

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                if(index.column() != 0):
                    return str('%.2f'%self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
                else:
                    return str(self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[section]
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data.index[section])
        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(self.__class__,self).flags(index)
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags


if __name__=='__main__':
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Field1']=np.arange(0,10,.5)
    df['Field2']=np.arange(0,10,.5)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    mymodel = PandasModel(df)
    table.setModel(mymodel)
    table.show()
    app.exec_()
```

You can easily change the model to edit or show the elements nicely based on your need. For more information refer to  [modelview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use ipython notebooks to drive pandas -- notebooks provide a nice clean way of incrementally building and interacting with pandas data structures, including HTML-ized display of dataframes:  http://ipython.org/notebook.html

Comment: The link doesn't point to any solution, just to iPython (now Jupyter) homepage. where are the "HTML-ized display of dataframes"? Is that what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16884805/774575), or are they just the cell output of `some_df.head (n)`?

Comment: Anyone who came across this may need: [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

I tested many of the suggestions here and none of them seem to run or install easily, especially for Python 3, but now I've written a function which is basically accomplishing what I wanted. Need to have these dataframes full-screen, and scrollable sometimes.

So in a Linux environment using Libreoffice Calc, inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220829/188451) from Unix and Linux StackExchange, here's what you can do in Python 3:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def viewDF(*dfs):
    filelist = ""
    for c, df in enumerate(dfs):    
        filename = 'tmp_df' + str(c) + '.csv'
        odsfile = 'tmp_df' + str(c) + '.ods'
        df.to_csv(filename)
        os.system("soffice --headless --convert-to ods  {}".format(filename))     
        filelist += odsfile + " "
    os.system("soffice --view {}".format(filelist)) 
    os.system("rm {}".format('tmp_df*'))
```

Use it like this:

```
viewDF(df1, df2, df3)
```

I learned something there, which is the Python 3 substitution syntax `{}".format` The opened files are read-only, in any case they are files which are later deleted, so it's effectively a GUI for dataframes. It will spawn multiple instances of Libreoffice Calc for each dataframe you give it, which you can view fullscreen on separate screens, and then once you close Calc, it cleans up after itself.

Comment: After testing many answers I was surprised to find that this was the best solution. I've modified it a bit:
`ending = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`
`filename = f'tmp_df_{ending}%s'`
`df.to_csv(filename%'csv')`
`os.system(f"soffice --headless --convert-to ods  {filename%'csv'}")`
`os.system(f"soffice --view {filename%'ods'}")`

Answer (score 2):

I've also been searching very simple gui. I was surprised that no one mentioned `gtabview`.

It is easy to install (just `pip3 install gtabview` ), and it loads data blazingly fast.
I recommend using gtabview if you are not using spyder or Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Pandas user myself, but a quick search for "pandas gui" turns up the Pandas project's [GSOC 2012 proposal](http://pandas.pydata.org/summerofcode2012.html):

> Currently the only way to interact with these objects is through the API. This project proposes to add a simple Qt or Tk GUI with which to view and manipulate these objects.

So, there's no GUI, but if you'd write one using Qt or Tk, the project might be interested in your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I think building a generally usable tool would be above my skill level!

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way is to use [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) to view the dataframe in Excel. It has excellent treatment of Pandas dataframes. Install as usual using

```
pip install xlwings
```

then just have Excel open while you are working  and

```
import xlwings as xw
xw.sheets.active.range("A1").value = df         # put df in currently active sheet
```

More sophisticated you can use `app = xw.App()` to open Excel and/or `xw.Book()` to create a new workbook from Excel. To create/switch between sheets I usually use a small custom function

```
def addActivate(wb, sheet, after=None, before=None):
    try:
        wb.sheets.add(sheet, after=after, before=before)
    except ValueError:
        wb.sheets(sheet).activate()

addActivate(xw.books.active, "newSheet")
xw.sheets.active.range("A1").value = df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub Atom with Hydrogen plugin. In Mac you can use Cmd+Shift keys to execute line by line. Even you can select only the variable and see inside. DataFrames are nicely display and you can even copy. I wrote a blog to show the way to configure these.
http://ojitha.blogspot.com.au/2016/08/atom-as-spark-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Can I propose `pivotablejs`?

It provides horizontal and vertical pivoting, filtering, graphing, sorting, and lots of different aggregations all in just a few lines in a Jupyter notebook (tip: right-click the [pop out] link and open in a new tab for increased flexibility)

```
!pip install pivottablejs
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui

pivot_ui(df, outfile_path='pivottablejs.html')
```

[image: Graphic pivoting example]

https://towardsdatascience.com/two-essential-pandas-add-ons-499c1c9b65de

Answer (score 0):

you can also use pandastable library

https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable

I found it very useful for my application

you can simply install pandastable using 'pip install pandastable'

my application works on pandas==0.23.4 and this version of pandas works well with pandastable