# Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work with Series and DataFrames on the terminal a lot. The default `__repr__` for a Series returns a reduced sample, with some head and tail values, but the rest missing.

Is there a builtin way to pretty-print the entire Series / DataFrame?  Ideally, it would support proper alignment, perhaps borders between columns, and maybe even color-coding for the different columns.

Comment: The reduced output is due to the default options which you can change using `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)` for example, the colouring is something else, I assume you are talking about colouring the html repr output. I don't think this is built in at all.

Answer (score 1522, accepted):

You can also use the [`option_context`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html), with one or more options:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

This will automatically return the options to their previous values.

If you are working on jupyter-notebook, using `display(df)` instead of `print(df)` will use jupyter rich display logic [(like so)](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display).

Comment: For anyone who wonder: when using jupyter, use `display(df)` instead of `print(df)`

Comment: This doesn't work on series, why?

Comment: In ipython it works for Series (i.e., in a non-Jupyter ipython).

Answer (score 1068):

No need to hack settings. There is a simple way:

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: It also doesn't try to split the dataframe in multiple rows if it's too wide.

Comment: A much simpler solution. It works when you just need to evaluate the full output without the cutoff

Comment: does not work for series

Answer (score 195):

Sure, if this comes up a lot, make a function like this one. You can even configure it to load every time you start IPython: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html

```
def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

As for coloring, getting too elaborate with colors sounds counterproductive to me, but I agree something like [bootstrap's `.table-striped`](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables) would be nice. You could always [create an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) to suggest this feature.

Answer (score 184):

After importing pandas, as an alternative to using the context manager, set such [**options**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) for displaying entire dataframes:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # or 1000
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # or 1000
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)  # or 199
```

For full list of useful options, see:

```
pd.describe_option('display')
```

Answer (score 74):

Use the tabulate package:

```
pip install tabulate
```

And consider the following example usage:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from tabulate import tabulate

c = """Chromosome Start End
chr1 3 6
chr1 5 7
chr1 8 9"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(c), sep="\s+", header=0)

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+--------------+---------+-------+
|    | Chromosome   |   Start |   End |
|----+--------------+---------+-------|
|  0 | chr1         |       3 |     6 |
|  1 | chr1         |       5 |     7 |
|  2 | chr1         |       8 |     9 |
+----+--------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestion, but it doesn't show the full table. It shows dots in the middle. How can I view all rows using tabulate?

Answer (score 52):

### Using `pd.options.display`

This answer is a variation of the prior [answer by lucidyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347783/832230). It makes the code more readable by avoiding the use of `set_option`.

After importing pandas, as an alternative to using the context manager, set such [**options**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) for displaying large dataframes:

```
def set_pandas_display_options() -> None:
    """Set pandas display options."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52432757/
    display = pd.options.display

    display.max_columns = 1000
    display.max_rows = 10_000
    display.max_colwidth = 199
    display.width = 1000
    # display.precision = 2  # set as needed
    # display.float_format = lambda x: '{:,.2f}'.format(x)  # set as needed

set_pandas_display_options()
```

After this, you can use either `display(df)` or just `df` if using a notebook, otherwise `print(df)`.

Regarding any columns containing floating point numbers while having the `object` dtype, such columns need to first be converted to the `float` dtype before the display precision will apply to them.

### Using `to_string`

Pandas 0.25.3 does have [`DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) and [`Series.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html) methods which accept formatting options.

### Using `to_markdown`

If what you need is markdown output, Pandas 1.0.0 has [`DataFrame.to_markdown`](https://dev.pandas.io/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) and [`Series.to_markdown`](https://dev.pandas.io/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_markdown.html) methods.

### Using `to_html`

If what you need is HTML output, Pandas 0.25.3 does have a [`DataFrame.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html) method but not a `Series.to_html`. Note that a `Series` can be [converted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) to a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 41):

If you are using Ipython Notebook (Jupyter). You can use HTML

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Simply using `display(df)` works for me.

Answer (score 16):

***just run this***

```
    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
    print(df)
```

just do this

> Output

```
Column
0    row 0
1    row 1
2    row 2
3    row 3
4    row 4
5    row 5
6    row 6
7    row 7
8    row 8
9    row 9
10  row 10
11  row 11
12  row 12
13  row 13
14  row 14
15  row 15
16  row 16
17  row 17
18  row 18
19  row 19
20  row 20
21  row 21
22  row 22
23  row 23
24  row 24
25  row 25
26  row 26
27  row 27
28  row 28
29  row 29
30  row 30
31  row 31
32  row 32
33  row 33
34  row 34
35  row 35
36  row 36
37  row 37
38  row 38
39  row 39
40  row 40
41  row 41
42  row 42
43  row 43
44  row 44
45  row 45
46  row 46
47  row 47
48  row 48
49  row 49
50  row 50
51  row 51
52  row 52
53  row 53
54  row 54
55  row 55
56  row 56
57  row 57
58  row 58
59  row 59
60  row 60
61  row 61
62  row 62
63  row 63
64  row 64
65  row 65
66  row 66
67  row 67
68  row 68
69  row 69
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
pd.set_option('display.height',1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',500)
pd.set_option('display.width',1000)
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Scripts

Nobody has proposed this simple plain-text solution:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(s.to_dict())
```

which produces results like the following:

```
{'% Diabetes': 0.06365372374283895,
 '% Obesity': 0.06365372374283895,
 '% Bachelors': 0.0,
 '% Poverty': 0.09548058561425843,
 '% Driving Deaths': 1.1775938892425206,
 '% Excessive Drinking': 0.06365372374283895}
```

#### Jupyter Notebooks

Additionally, when using Jupyter notebooks, this is a great solution.

Note: `pd.Series()` has no `.to_html()` so it must be converted to `pd.DataFrame()`

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(s.to_frame().to_html()))
```

which produces results like the following:

[image: Display pd.Series as table in Jupyter notebooks]

Answer (score 7):

[datascroller](https://github.com/baogorek/datascroller) was created in part to solve this problem.

```sh
pip install datascroller
```

It loads the dataframe into a terminal view you can "scroll" with your mouse or arrow keys, kind of like an Excel workbook at the terminal that supports querying, highlighting, etc.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datascroller import scroll

# Call `scroll` with a Pandas DataFrame as the sole argument:
my_df = pd.read_csv('<path to your csv>')
scroll(my_df)
```

Disclosure: I am one of the authors of datascroller

Comment: Tried using this in jupyter notebook, and it consistently killed the kernel.

Comment: Hi @rbonallo, it is a tool for the terminal only. That would be great if it could work right in the notebook but it relies on the curses library which is all terminal characters. Looks like it's possible to connect to an existing ipython kernel (SO 9977446) so that would be a neat trick if you had a terminal window just for data scrolling next to your jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 7):

You can set [`expand_frame_repr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) to `False`:

> `display.expand_frame_repr : boolean`
>
> Whether to print out the full DataFrame repr for wide DataFrames
> across multiple lines, `max_columns` is still respected, but the output
> will wrap-around across multiple “pages” if its width exceeds
> `display.width`.
>
> `[default: True]`

---

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

---

For more details read [How to Pretty-Print Pandas DataFrames and Series](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-pretty-print-pandas-dataframes-and-series-b301fa78bb6c)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using below method. just pass the total no. of columns present in the DataFrame as arg to

> 'display.max_columns'

For eg :

```
df= DataFrame(..)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', df.shape[1]):
    print(df)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using display() function. This would automatically use Horizontal and vertical scroll bars and with this you can display different datasets easily instead of using print().

```
display(dataframe)
```

display() supports proper alignment also.

However if you want to make the dataset more beautiful you can check `pd.option_context()`. It has lot of options to clearly show the dataframe.

Note - I am using Jupyter Notebooks.