# IPython notebook ~ Using javascript to run python code?

Tags: javascript, python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute python code through javascript directly:

1. I fire up IPython Notebook on Chrome
2. Using chrome developer tools I open up the javascript console.

In the javascript consolde, I type: `IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("2+2")`

[image]

But I get a strange output: `"6CEA73CC644648DDA978FDD6A913E519"`

Is there any way to take advantage of all the IPython javascript functions available, to run python code from the javascript console as depicted in the image? I'm sure there's a way but I've been beating at it for way too long and thought I would post here.

(I need this to build an app on top of IPython)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can call Python code execution from JavaScript with `Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute()` function.

Depend on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/craigsdennis/ddfaa99a6291f05fef879329821872ee) from Craig Dennis you can insert this code in Jupyter cell and run it

```
%%javascript
window.executePython = function(python) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var callbacks = {
            iopub: {
                output: (data) => resolve(data.content.text.trim())
            }
        };
        Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute(`${python}`, callbacks);    
    });
}

function Log_out(r)
{ console.log(r); };

var code = 
'for i in range(1,6):'+
'    print( "#" + str(i))';

window.executePython( code )
    .then(result => Log_out(result)); // Log out
```

Result would be output to browser javascript console.

Comment: In order to transfer large dataframes to javascript it might be required to turn off preview features of pandas: 

with pandas.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None, "display.width", None):
    print(dataFrame)

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of this blogpost? http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/

I think the exact way he uses doesn't work anymore, but maybe it can get you a step forward

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried that + in the comments there is a solution for IPython 2.0 and 3.1, but I haven't been able to get any of the solutions to work with IPython 4.0.0 (also tried coming up some solutions but to no avail)

Comment: Maybe ask the question as part of a github issue on the jupyter repo. Had good experience getting help that way

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

After spending two days on it, here is the solution that worked for me.

To run Python code I am simpy using 'Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute'. To get the answer from it I found usefull information at this link: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comms.html

```
from ipykernel.comm import Comm

js_input = [] #case willing to track

def func_edit(cobj,text):
    my_comm = Comm(target_name=cobj) #this is the callback
    my_comm.send('' if  text == '' else 'Return: ' + text)

    global js_input
    js_input.append(f'origin={cobj} text={text}')
    
    
    
from IPython.display import display, HTML
html = """
<script>
    var comm_name = "this_control";
    function fcalc(x)
    {
        // here I am passing to the Python function the value to edit and the address for getting the return value
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("func_edit('" + comm_name + "','" + x.value + "')")
    }
    Jupyter.notebook.kernel.comm_manager.register_target(comm_name, function(comm, msg) 
        {
          // comm is the frontend comm instance,  msg is the comm_open message, which can carry data

            // Register handlers for later messages:
            comm.on_msg(function(msg) { 
                document.getElementById("out").value = msg.content.data;
            });
            
            //comm.on_close(function(msg) {...});
            //comm.send({'foo': 40}); what is it??
        });
</script>
<label for="in">Input:</label>
<input type="text" id="in" name="in" oninput="fcalc(this)">
<label for="out">Out:</label>
<input type="text" id="out">
"""
display(HTML(html))
```

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to isolate a minimum viable implementation, I was able to get responses back from the IPython kernel in just a couple of steps using essentially the same approach as [ChrCury78](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69578912/4376000).

Since I want to use the data returned from Python within Javascript, in these examples I just stored the message contents in a member on `console`. (Unlike what ChrCury78 did, where he pushed the result to the output of the notebook cell.) In my real extension, I'll probably just attach it to a name on `Jupyter`, or maybe an object of my own creation.

```js
>> Jupyter.notebook.kernel.comm_manager.register_target("mycomm", (comm, msg) => {comm.on_msg( m => {console.retval = m.content.data})})
<- undefined
>> Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute("from ipykernel.comm import Comm; Comm(target_name='mycomm').send('FOO')")
<- "{hex UID}"
>> console.retval
<- "FOO"
```

Multi-line Python code worked just fine, too; and, since I'd already imported `Comm`, I didn't need to import it again:

```
>> Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute("l = []\nfor x in range(5):\n  l.append(x)\nComm(target_name='mycomm').send(l)")
<- "{hex UID}"
>> console.retval
<- Array(5) [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

If you want to keep the kernel namespace unpolluted afterward, you could add a `del Comm` to the end of the Python command.

I'll definitely be writing wrapper functions of some kind for both of these operations.

---

This is with Python 3.9.11 and the following packages installed:

```
ipykernel                         6.9.2
ipython                           8.1.1
ipython-genutils                  0.2.0
ipywidgets                        7.7.0

jupyter                           1.0.0
jupyter-client                    7.1.2
jupyter-console                   6.4.3
jupyter-contrib-core              0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions      0.5.1
jupyter-core                      4.9.2
jupyter-highlight-selected-word   0.2.0
jupyter-latex-envs                1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.4.1
jupyterlab-pygments               0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets                1.1.0
```