# Print numpy array without ellipsis

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to print a numpy array without truncation. I have seen other solutions but those don't seem to work.

Here is the code snippet:

```
total_list = np.array(total_list)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
print(total_list)
```

And this is what the output looks like:

```
22        A
23        G
24        C
25        T
26        A
27        A
28        A
29        G
         ..
232272    G
232273    T
232274    G
232275    C
232276    T
232277    C
232278    G
232279    T
```

This is the entire code. I might be making a mistake in type casting.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



seqs = pd.read_csv('BAP_GBS_BTXv2_imp801.hmp.csv')
plts = pd.read_csv('BAP16_PlotPlan.csv')

required_rows = np.array([7,11,14,19,22,31,35,47,50,55,58,63,66,72,74,79,82,87,90,93,99])
total_list = []


for i in range(len(required_rows)):
    curr_row = required_rows[i];
    print(curr_row)
    for j in range(len(plts.RW)):
        if(curr_row == plts.RW[j]):
            curr_plt = plts.PI[j]
            curr_range = plts.RA1[j]
            curr_plt = curr_plt.replace("_", "").lower()
            if curr_plt in seqs.columns:
                new_item = [curr_row,curr_range,seqs[curr_plt]]
                total_list.append(new_item)
                print(seqs[curr_plt]) 


total_list = np.array(total_list)
'''
np.savetxt("foo.csv", total_list[:,2], delimiter=',',fmt='%s')
total_list[:,2].tofile('seqs.csv',sep=',',format='%s')
'''
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

print(total_list)
```

Comment: It works for me, maybe your total_list is not a numpy array?

Comment: It is not how numpy arrays look. Are you sure it is not a pandas Series?

Comment: are you trying to print to a file?

Comment: That was the actual intent. But had the same problem. So I m trying to print it on the terminal first.

Comment: does this file need to be human readable? or is it for the purpose of storing the data?

Comment: Numpy has built in functions to do either... [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) can be configured to write a standard csv file, and [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) can save to a numpy specific binary format.

Comment: Please check the edit. I have tried that. It also saves the csv in truncated format.

Answer (score 32):

use the following snippet to get no ellipsis.

```py
import numpy
import sys
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

**EDIT:**

If you have a `pandas.DataFrame` use the following snippet to print your array:

```
def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

Or you can use the [pandas.DataFrame.to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) method to get the desired result.

**EDIT':**

An earlier version of this post suggested the option below

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
```

Technically, this might work, however, the numpy documentation specifies int and None as allowed types. Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html.

Comment: python and numpy version?

Comment: Python 3.5.2, numpy 1.11.1

Comment: @Harjatin maybe the other print is not formatted properly (the first one in the loop)

Comment: I commented all the other print statements. The output is still truncated.

Comment: @Harjatin are you sure it is not a pandas.DataFrame? read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-the-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: At least from 1.16.5, this doesn't work: `ValueError: threshold must be numeric and non-NAN, try sys.maxsize for untruncated representation`, so use `sys.maxsize`.

Answer (score 5):

You can get around the weird Numpy repr/print behavior by changing it to a `list`:

```
print list(total_list)
```

should print out your list of 2-element np arrays.

Comment: This still gives the same output

Comment: Weird - does it happen if you use `total_list.tolist()` as well?

Comment: you probably run a different code what you edit :)) I can confirm both of the answers work fine. add a `print("hello")` or whatever

Comment: What is `total_list` to start with?

Comment: numpy's printing is more useful though for most cases, because it is more readable ― no commas between the numbers..

Answer (score 4):

You are **not** printing numpy arrays.

Add the following line after the imports:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I am little confused through, shouldn't `total_list = np.array(total_list)` covert DataFrame to numpy array ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#for a 2d array
def print_full(x):
    dim = x.shape
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', dim[0])#dim[0] = len(x)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', dim[1])
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
    pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that as of Python 3, the threshold can no longer be unlimited.

Therefore, the recommended option is:

```
import numpy
import sys
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```