# error in reading csv file content on S3 using boto

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto

I am using `boto` to read a `csv` file and parse it contents. This is the code I wrote:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import pandas as pd
import io

conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId, sKeyId)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)

# Get the Key object of the given key, in the bucket
k = Key(bucket, srcFileName)

content = k.get_contents_as_string()
reader = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content))

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

But I am getting error at read_csv line:

`TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

How can I resolve this error and parse the contents of the csv file present on `S3`

**UPDATE:** if I use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO` then the `print(row)` line only prints 1st row of the csv. How do I loop over it?

This is my current code:

```
    import boto3

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id = keyId, aws_secret_access_key = sKeyId)

    obj = s3.Object(bucketName, srcFileName)

    content = obj.get_contents_as_string()
    reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(content), header=None)

    count = 0
    for index, row in reader.iterrows():
        print(row[1])
```

When I execute this I get `AttributeError: 's3.Object' object has no attribute 'get_contents_as_string'` error

Comment: can you try `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`?

Comment: @salient how do I loop over all the rows in the csv file? When I use `BytesIO` and do `for row in reader: print(row)` it only prints 1st row of the csv file

Comment: have you removed the `[0]`?

Comment: @salient yes I removed [0]

Comment: oh sorry, you get a pandas dataframe back from that operation. can't you just do something along these lines to print: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-the-entire-pandas-series-dataframe

Comment: If you must iterate over rows: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: @salient thanks I was able to execute that but now running into different related issues. Somehow when I execute it on an AWS server it throws error on `import boto`. I checked installed packages and there is `boto3` but no `boto`. Also I do not have permissions to install a new package. Does this works only for `boto` and not`boto3`?

Comment: The syntax for `boto3` is a bit different http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html but the principles are the same

Comment: @salient I am getting `AttributeError: 's3.Object' object has no attribute 'get_contents_as_string'` when trying boto3. I have updated my code in my post above in update section

Comment: try `s3.get_object()['Body'].read()`

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object