# How to display all rows in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I am using Try Jupyter! https://try.jupyter.org/

I have following R code to display data (120 rows).

```
require(plyr)

seed=42
blocksize = 4
N = 120
set.seed(seed)
block = rep(1:ceiling(N/blocksize), each = blocksize)
a1 = data.frame(block, rand=runif(length(block)), envelope= 1: length(block))
a2 = a1[order(a1$block,a1$rand),]
a2$arm = rep(c("Arm 1", "Arm 2"),times = length(block)/2)
assign = a2[order(a2$envelope),]

head(assign,120)
```

How can I display all details of data instead of having these dots ( ... ) between rows in the middle?
[image]

When I tried this R script at my local server, I only got 30 rows of data and break of rows was between 8 and 23.

I was reading other question on Stackoverflow, and it mentioned about Pandas series.

I am not sure how this case could be related to Pandas (since I did not use any Python directly here).

My question is where do I change so that it would display all rows? (in local server or possibly at https://try.jupyter.org/ as well)

Do I have execute Python script to server?

Comment: Are we running on local server only? no change on https://try.jupyter.org ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I saw the python tag and jumped to an answer.

Comment: Any suggestion regards to making this work (displaying whole rows)?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I don't know R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Answer (score 20):

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
```

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: A little more generic: `pd.options.display.max_rows = None` displays all rows.

Answer (score 5):

to have no limit for one dataframe `df`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
  display(df)
```

otherwise

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
```

as suggested in a previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I have to add this line on the top.
For example (`600` and `200`).

```
options(repr.matrix.max.rows=600, repr.matrix.max.cols=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

Comment: will this really work? the question is about R. I think you should motivate this answer...