# How to show all results value in jupter output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, correlation

I try to view correlation value and its corresponding feature but when run code it just show the part of it. The code and output in below

```
x= correlation.label.sort_values(ascending = False)
```

[image]

I try to use print (*x) and [print(x) for x in x] but it show correlation value and no corresponding features

If any one can help me to show total list..

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554597/how-to-display-all-rows-in-jupyter-notebook) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following line of code: `pd.options.display.max_rows = None`

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4.0/user_guide/options.html

> display.max_rows
>
> Default: 60
>
> This sets the maximum number of rows pandas should output when
> printing out various output. For example, this value determines
> whether the repr() for a dataframe prints out fully or just a
> truncated or summary repr. ‘None’ value means unlimited.