# How to print out each single unique value in a column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, unique

entered:

```
train['brand_name'].unique()
```

get the result:

```
array([nan, 'Razer', 'Target', ..., 'Astroglide', 'Cumberland Bay',
   'Kids Only'], dtype=object)
```

I need to see every value. there are some values represented by .... i want to know how to show those too.

thanks!

Comment: `train['brain_name'].unique().tolist()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to (pretty) print the entire Pandas Series / DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-the-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: i don't know how to accept Scott's answer. it is a comment not an answer format. pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display all the rows in an IPython console or Jupyter then you should set the `pd.options.display.max_rows` to a value no less than the length of the Pandas Series you want to print (like `pd.options.display.max_rows = len(train)`), or you can just set it to `None`. You can do it in a context --`with` allows your change to be temporary.

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    print train['brand_name'].value_counts()
    #or, alternatively
    #print pd.Series(train['brand_name'].unique())
```

More on Pandas' display-related options: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, train['brand_name'].unique().tolist())))
```

Explanation:

- `\n` represents new line character for printing.
- `map(str, lst)` maps to strings in case you have non-text data in your list.