# Not seeing the full column, in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-science-experience, watson-studio

In my dataframe, I have a one column which has a very large set with a lot of information.

When I do:

```
df.head()
```

It crops the column data so I can't see it all.  Any ideas how stop the cropping and have scrollbar instead?

Thanks

Comment: I like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691921/2901002), not sure if need this.

Comment: @jezrael That's nice I'll accept that as a solution, if you want?

Comment: I really like create answer, but then people of SO kill me, because dupe :( But if accept some oldier unaccepting my solution(s), it will be very nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to just set `display.max_colwidth` to `-1` like:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `df.head()` prints the first few rows of a dataframe, `df.tail()` the last rows. It is 5 by default, but you could say, e.g., `df.head(20)` to get 20 rows.

`df` should return the entire data frame and with `df[n:m]` you can return the rows from n to m, just `df[:5]` is the same as the head function.

[See here for more on data frames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#dataframes).

Answer (score 0):

One to do this:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 2000)
```