# Rendering an 12k row dataframe with MultiIndex in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

A generalized recreation of the table I'm having issues with, which will come out being a table with 12000 rows and a MultiIndex. The big issue: I can't get this table to display in a rendered version of a Jupyter Notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12000, 6), columns=list('ABCDCD'))

second_cols = ([''] * 2) + ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns,second_cols])
df = df.swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(1)
df
```

My company uses proprietary software that lets us turn an *.ipynb file* into a interactive report. However, most of my issues are Jupyter notebook-level. Here's what I've tried and what's happened:

1. Just display `df`: The tables print out, but only show rows [0:29, 19930:12000] and there is no sorting available.
2. `display(HTML(df.to_html()))`: gives me the following error:

   > IOPub data rate exceeded.
   >     The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
   >     to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
   >     To change this limit, set the config variable
   >     `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.`
3. DataViz and GoogleCharts do not support MultiIndexes.

**Any ideas to make my dataframe render?! Perhaps packages that can paginate my table, etc? Note the big issue here is *the MultiIndex*.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to (pretty) print the entire Pandas Series / DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-the-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: @ALollz, this question is specifically about rendering a MultiIndexed dataframe and the struggles to print them, not just a generic Series/DF :)