# I have difficulties in getting the complete list of output in Spyder (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.7

I am new in python programming. I am working on a big matrix of data. While trying to use the pandas function .nunique, to count the elements referring to the elements of the first row, I am given back only the first 30 and the last 30 rows of the complete output. The mid part is missing and reported by the three dots (...)

```
readCSV=pd.read_csv('/Users/.../test.csv',delimiter=',')  
nuniq=readCSV.groupby('#RIC')['Date-Time'].nunique()  
print(nuniq)
```

Here I report the central part of the output as it appears in the console:

```
DE113522=    1112256  
DE113527=    1112256

                ... 

IT512708=     307507  
IT513584=     303438
```

Knowing my data, there are at least 50 other rows not appearing.

Is there a way to get all the rows of the output?
I am working with Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pretty print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: Please take a look at [Pandas' options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html). I'm sure you'll find the option you need there.