# Issue with scraping Understat chart data using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape chart data under 'Timing Sheet' tab at https://understat.com/match/9457.

My approach is to use BeautifulSoap and Selenium but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Set the url we want
xg_url = 'https://understat.com/match/9457'

# Use requests to download the webpage
xg_data = requests.get(xg_url)

# Get the html code for the webpage
xg_html = xg_data.content

# Parse the html using bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(xg_html, 'lxml')

#print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.title)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

# Set up the Selenium driver (in this case I am using the Chrome browser)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Tell the driver to navigate to the page url
driver.get(xg_url)

# Grab the html code from the webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# Get the table headers using 3 chained find operations
# 1. Find the div containing the table (div class = chemp jTable)
# 2. Find the table within that div
# 3. Find all 'th' elements where class = sort
headers = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'scheme-block'}).find('div').find_all('div',attrs={'class':'chartjs-tooltip team-home is-hide'})

headers

# Iterate over headers, get the text from each item, and add the results to headers_list
headers_list = []
for header in headers:
    headers_list.append(header.get_text(strip=True))
print(headers_list)

# You can also simply call elements like tables directly instead of using find('table') if you are only looking for the first instance of that element
body = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'scheme-block'}).div

# Create a master list for row data
all_rows_list = []
# For each row in the table body
for tr in body.find_all('tr'):
# Get data from each cell in the row
    row = tr.find_all('td')
# Create list to save current row data to
    current_row = []
# For each item in the row variable
for item in row:
# Add the text data to the current_row list
    current_row.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
# Add the current row data to the master list
    all_rows_list.append(current_row)

# Create a dataframe where the rows = all_rows_list and columns = headers_list
xg_df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows_list, columns=headers_list)
xg_df
```

This code is taken from a different task and I've change a few things to scrape div instead of table but looking at data, it doesn't seem its scraping charts yet.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. All the data is in there if you look at the `<script>` tags. Most cases it's already in a nice json format and just requires a bit of spliting the strings to get the structure. In this particular case, you see though it looks a little different:

```
<script>
var shotsData   = JSON.parse('\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22271478\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x226\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22....
```

But not to fear, it still can be worked with using some regex. I also converted the shots data, and roster data from json to a dataframe, but the match data is a single key with all the values so didn't bother with that since it would just be 1 row. You may not even need the dataframe and just work of the json format, but it's all there for you:

```
import requests
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://understat.com/match/9457')

shotsData = re.search("shotsData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(shotsData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
shotsObj = json.loads(decoded_string)

match_info = re.search("match_info\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(match_info.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
matchObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


rostersData = re.search("rostersData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(rostersData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
rostersObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


# Shots Data into a DataFrame
away_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['a'])
home_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['h'])
shots_df = away_shots_df.append(home_shots_df)



# Rosters Data into a DataFrame
away_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['a'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    away_rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(temp_df)

home_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['h'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    home_rosters_df = home_rosters_df.append(temp_df)    

rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(home_rosters_df)  

teams_dict = {'a':matchObj['team_a'], 'h':matchObj['team_h']}
match_title = matchObj['team_h'] + ' vs. ' + matchObj['team_a']
```

**Output:**

```
print (shots_df)
                     X          ...                             xG
0   0.9069999694824219          ...            0.40696778893470764
1   0.8190000152587891          ...            0.05737118795514107
2                 0.94          ...             0.5754774808883667
3   0.9319999694824219          ...            0.02447112277150154
4                0.725          ...            0.02365683950483799
5   0.7759999847412109          ...           0.026968277990818024
6   0.8619999694824219          ...            0.08384699374437332
7   0.7659999847412109          ...           0.013624735176563263
0   0.9269999694824219          ...           0.055443812161684036
1                0.835          ...            0.03609708696603775
2   0.9059999847412109          ...            0.03347432240843773
3   0.9769999694824218          ...            0.07148116827011108
4   0.9869999694824219          ...             0.9712227582931519
5   0.8390000152587891          ...           0.028583310544490814
6   0.8580000305175781          ...            0.07498162239789963
7    0.924000015258789          ...            0.04431726038455963
8   0.9569999694824218          ...            0.48726019263267517
9   0.9540000152587891          ...            0.06847231835126877
10                0.91          ...            0.07779974490404129
11   0.875999984741211          ...            0.04344969615340233
12  0.8780000305175781          ...           0.019344232976436615
13   0.789000015258789          ...           0.043812621384859085
14  0.9419999694824219          ...            0.34188181161880493
15                 0.9          ...            0.05839642137289047
16  0.9069999694824219          ...           0.043319668620824814
17  0.8490000152587891          ...           0.058181893080472946
18  0.9019999694824219          ...            0.09132817387580872
19                0.87          ...            0.11395697295665741
20  0.8819999694824219          ...           0.035116128623485565

[29 rows x 20 columns]
```

**ADDITIONAL**

As suspected, the Timing Chart is generated by the `'xG`' column in the `shotsData`. It's merely a running sum of the xP for each team. I also provide the line chart at the end, where you can hover over the graph. Check out [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/). I have used it before and it's great, however, beyond the scope of the question. But here is a quick one I did:

[Timing Chart](https://plot.ly/~jschvach/94/timing-chart/)

```
#########################################################################
# Timing Chart is an aggregation (running sum) of xG from the shotsData
#########################################################################
import numpy as np

# Convert 'minute' astype int and sort the dataframe by 'minute'
shots_df['minute'] = shots_df['minute'].astype(int)
shots_df['xG'] = shots_df['xG'].astype(float)

timing_chart_df = shots_df[['h_a', 'minute', 'xG']].sort_values('minute')
timing_chart_df['h_a'] = timing_chart_df['h_a'].map(teams_dict)

# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()

# Aggregate xG within the same minute
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.groupby(['h_a','minute'], as_index=False)['xG'].sum()

# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(timing_chart_df['minute'].max() + 1)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timing_chart_df['h_a'].unique(), min_idx], names=['h_a', 'minute'])


# Calculate the running sum
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.set_index(['h_a', 'minute']).reindex(m_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
timing_chart_df['running_sum_xG'] = timing_chart_df.groupby('h_a')['xG'].cumsum()


timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_df.pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_T_df.reset_index().rename(columns={timing_chart_T_df.index.name:match_title})
```

**Output:**

```
print (timing_chart_T_df.to_string())
minute West Ham vs. Fulham         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85       86       87        88        89        90        91        92
0                   Fulham  0.406968  0.464339  1.039816  1.039816  1.039816  1.039816  1.039816  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.064288  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.087944  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.114913  1.198760  1.198760  1.198760  1.19876  1.19876  1.198760  1.198760  1.198760  1.198760  1.212384
1                 West Ham  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.055444  0.091541  0.091541  0.091541  0.091541  0.091541  0.091541  1.167719  1.167719  1.196302  1.196302  1.196302  1.196302  1.271284  1.271284  1.315601  1.315601  1.315601  1.802862  1.802862  1.871334  1.949134  1.949134  1.992583  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.011928  2.055740  2.055740  2.055740  2.397622  2.397622  2.397622  2.397622  2.397622  2.397622  2.397622  2.456018  2.499338  2.55752  2.55752  2.648848  2.762805  2.797921  2.797921  2.797921
```

**Plotly Line Chart:**

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='username', api_key='xxxxxxxxxxx')

plotly.tools.set_config_file(world_readable=True)

# Create traces
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == 'a']['minute'],
    y = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == 'a']['running_sum_xG'],
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'Fulham',
    line = dict(
        color = ('#E5E64B'),
        width = 4)
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == 'h']['minute'],
    y = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == 'h']['running_sum_xG'],
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'West Ham',
    line = dict(
        color = ('#00BCD4'),
        width = 4)
)

data_comp = [trace0, trace1]

layout_comp = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=600,



    title='Timing Chart',
    plot_bgcolor='#3E3E40',
    hovermode='x',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Minute',
        ticklen=15,
        zeroline=True,
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='#39393B',
        gridwidth=2,
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='xG',
        ticklen=5,
        gridwidth=2,
        zeroline=True,
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='#39393B',
    ),
)

fig_comp = go.Figure(data=data_comp, layout=layout_comp)
py.iplot(fig_comp, filename='line-mode')
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what these values are. I can see xG values but don't think they are in order maybe. My primary intention is to get the values of the graph on _Timing Chart_ so I can recreate it. Any ideas how that can be done?

Comment: Correct, they are not in order. But you can easily sort the dataframe by time (as there is a time column in there I believe. And actually if you’re plotting it, it should put that in order as long as you’re clarifying to put time on the x axis and the column represents a numerical value and not categorical/text. But to you’re 2nd point, I totally misunderstood the part where you say you want the “Timing Chart”, but I see what you mean now. I’ll be back at my laptop within the hour and look for that. just need to investigate where the site is getting that data to plot it.

Comment: My guess is they might be aggregating those numbers and doing an interpolation. Like I said, I’ll look at it as soon as I sit down at my desk.

Comment: @Alludy1962, I updated the solution. Be sure to accept it if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay first of all thank you very very much. This is a masterpiece. Now I am primarily looking to get the graph data as text output. If I do `print (timing_chart_df)`, I get the running sum of xG for `a` till 30 mins and for `h` from 63 to 92? Any way I can get complete print of minutes and running sum of xG for both teams here (preferably in just 4 lines with columns i.e. time (a), xG (a), time (h) & xG (h))?

Comment: `a` is the away team and `h` is home team. The entire 0-92 minutes is there for both. Notice the `.. .. ... ... ...` between minute 29 and minute 63? That means there's data between those, just not printing out. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe) and adjust your presences. I'm not sure what you mean by wanting just 4 lines? what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I meant that I wanted the output in horizontal coloums instead of vertical rows i.e. just 4 rows i.e. time (a), xG (a), time (h) & xG (h) and their corresponding values in coloums.

Comment: ah ok! I gotcha. Ya, I'll do that really quick. give me a few minutes and I'll add it onto the end of the solution above. really quick though, you really mean it'll be 3 rows, since the time will be the same for home and away. Correct?

Comment: actually will be 2 rows. The column names will the be the minute. Just updated now. but I'll put it here as well: `timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_df.pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')`

Comment: Ah thanks a ton. Works beautifully. One last (really) thing, how can I add a bit of legend in the text output? I would like the match title as first line and replace home and away with actual team names? Sorry I am noob with python.

Comment: No worries. We can easily replace the ‘h’ and ‘a’ with team names and put a title in. I’ll comment once I update it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Looking forward to it.

Comment: sure can! Will do that within the hour

Comment: Got it. but please post it up as a new question and I'll post the solution there. most won't mind a quick question beyond the original, but continuing to extend the original question, even after the original question has been well answered is not something you want to get into the habit of doing. It's best to ask a single question (and sure use comments for clarification or a quick extension), but when it starts into. "you answered it, now can you do this?" then, "You did this, can you do that?", then "You did that, how can I do something else?", etc, etc. is not the objective of the platform.

Comment: it'll also help your reputation as you post more good questions. take a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a few guidelines. Also comment here right before you post up the new question so I know to go look for it and post the solution for you.

Comment: Yeah I can understand. It makes more sense. The new question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942726/add-data-from-web-scrapping-in-python Thanks again.