# Add data from web-scraping in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have this python script for getting xG values from understat.com (special thanks to @chitown88).

I want to add an asterisk (*) to the team name that has recieved at least one red flag in the match. For e.g. in https://understat.com/match/9458 Huddersfield received a red card so in output if there can be an * next to name i.e. Huddersfield *.

Any ideas?

Here is my python script:

```
import requests
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://understat.com/match/9458')

shotsData = re.search("shotsData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(shotsData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
shotsObj = json.loads(decoded_string)

match_info = re.search("match_info\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(match_info.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
matchObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


rostersData = re.search("rostersData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(rostersData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
rostersObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


# Shots Data into a DataFrame
away_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['a'])
home_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['h'])
shots_df = away_shots_df.append(home_shots_df)



# Rosters Data into a DataFrame
away_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['a'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    away_rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(temp_df)

home_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['h'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    home_rosters_df = home_rosters_df.append(temp_df)

rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(home_rosters_df)

teams_dict = {'a':matchObj['team_a'], 'h':matchObj['team_h']}
match_title = matchObj['team_h'] + ' vs. ' + matchObj['team_a']

#print (shots_df)

# Cumulative chart of xG from the shotsData
import numpy as np

# Convert 'minute' astype int and sort the dataframe by 'minute'
shots_df['minute'] = shots_df['minute'].astype(int)
shots_df['xG'] = shots_df['xG'].astype(float)

timing_chart_df = shots_df[['h_a', 'minute', 'xG']].sort_values('minute')
timing_chart_df['h_a'] = timing_chart_df['h_a'].map(teams_dict)

# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()

# Aggregate xG within the same minute
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.groupby(['h_a','minute'], as_index=False)['xG'].sum()

# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(timing_chart_df['minute'].max() + 1)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timing_chart_df['h_a'].unique(), min_idx], names=['h_a', 'minute'])


# Calculate the running sum
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.set_index(['h_a', 'minute']).reindex(m_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
timing_chart_df['running_sum_xG'] = timing_chart_df.groupby('h_a')['xG'].cumsum()


timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_df.pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_T_df.reset_index().rename(columns={timing_chart_T_df.index.name:match_title})

print (timing_chart_T_df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to see you again.

You can simply do a check on the sums of the red cards in the dataframes:

```
if away_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    a_red_card = '*'
else:
    a_red_card = ''


if home_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    h_red_card = '*'
else:
    h_red_card = ''
```

And then concatenate that onto the text where you want it: ie:

```
teams_dict = {'a':matchObj['team_a']+a_red_card, 'h':matchObj['team_h']+h_red_card}
```

Full Code:

```
import requests
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://understat.com/match/9458')

shotsData = re.search("shotsData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(shotsData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
shotsObj = json.loads(decoded_string)

match_info = re.search("match_info\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(match_info.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
matchObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


rostersData = re.search("rostersData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(rostersData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
rostersObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


# Shots Data into a DataFrame
away_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['a'])
home_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['h'])
shots_df = away_shots_df.append(home_shots_df)



# Rosters Data into a DataFrame
away_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['a'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    away_rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(temp_df)



home_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['h'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    home_rosters_df = home_rosters_df.append(temp_df)    

rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(home_rosters_df) 


if away_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    a_red_card = '*'
else:
    a_red_card = ''


if home_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    h_red_card = '*'
else:
    h_red_card = ''

teams_dict = {'a':matchObj['team_a']+a_red_card, 'h':matchObj['team_h']+h_red_card}
match_title = matchObj['team_h'] + ' vs. ' + matchObj['team_a']


#########################################################################
# Timing Chart is an aggregation (running sum) of xG from the shotsData
#########################################################################
import numpy as np

# Convert 'minute' astype int and sort the dataframe by 'minute'
shots_df['minute'] = shots_df['minute'].astype(int)
shots_df['xG'] = shots_df['xG'].astype(float)

timing_chart_df = shots_df[['h_a', 'minute', 'xG']].sort_values('minute')
timing_chart_df['h_a'] = timing_chart_df['h_a'].map(teams_dict)

# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()

# Aggregate xG within the same minute
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.groupby(['h_a','minute'], as_index=False)['xG'].sum()

# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(timing_chart_df['minute'].max() + 1)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timing_chart_df['h_a'].unique(), min_idx], names=['h_a', 'minute'])


# Calculate the running sum
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.set_index(['h_a', 'minute']).reindex(m_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
timing_chart_df['running_sum_xG'] = timing_chart_df.groupby('h_a')['xG'].cumsum()


timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_df.pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_T_df.reset_index().rename(columns={timing_chart_T_df.index.name:match_title})


from datetime import datetime

home_team = matchObj['team_h']+h_red_card
away_team = matchObj['team_a']+a_red_card

league = matchObj['league']
season = matchObj['season']
date = matchObj['date']
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date = datetime_object.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')

results_df = pd.DataFrame([[league, season, date, home_team, away_team]], columns = ['League','Season','Date','Home team','Away team'])

home_xg_sum = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == home_team].pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
away_xg_sum = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == away_team].pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')



data = [league, season, date, home_team, away_team] + home_xg_sum.values.tolist()[0] + away_xg_sum.values.tolist()[0]
cols =  ['League','Season','Date','Home team','Away team'] + list(home_xg_sum.columns) + list(away_xg_sum.columns)


results_df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns = cols)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results_df.to_string())
  League Season                         Date         Home team      Away team    0    1    2    3    4    5    6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14       15       16       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42       43       44       45       46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85
0    EPL   2018  Saturday, February 23, 2019  Newcastle United  Huddersfield*  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.52089  0.52089  0.52089  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.650563  0.650563  0.650563  0.713521  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.780235  0.862191  0.862191  0.862191  0.972581  1.00803  1.00803  2.01324  2.01324  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.248354  2.248354  2.248354  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.484387  2.484387  2.624275  2.624275  2.755339  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.133949
```

Comment: Okay, please don't punch me (xD) but I would prefer few small changes if you don't mind. Here is an example https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=1ff030ea1af35f06f8303927d7ea62b3d1b62f9169ae4a4c0882f2a408f087aa441d5fc9c59ece5e05ea175ecce15378086f8a160b75022be1e55fb329c50a1f. Of course, don't need exactly like that but whatever info can be easily included would be really really appreciated.

Comment: "You're killing me smalls!" J/k, I'll take a look

Comment: Yup. No worries. :-)