# How to show all column content in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to show content of a dataframe that I created. The problem is that it shows only part of the column content:

[image]

Is there an option to see all the columns' content?

Comment: I usually use: `for i in df.loc[:10, 'col']: print(i)`.

Comment: `df["recomended movies random"].values`?

Comment: For list of all options : `pd.describe_option('display')`

Comment: checkout : >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `dataframe.head(n=100)`. Just change the value of n to how many items you want to display