# how to print/extract all rows and columns from the console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pycharm

i want to print or extract all columns and rows from my result data. The data is 61 rows and columns. The console displays like 6 or 7 columns and rows and fills the rest with dots but I need to obtain all the numbers. I uploaded an image of my data in the console. 
[Image of the data with dots and missing columns and rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY0DD.jpg)

Your help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the code you are currently using to output it?

Comment: You could print out each row individually with a for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: @Alex it's a very long code with an ordinary differential equation applied, but i just wrote "print("final results: ",  df)" to print the data.

Comment: @DamienBaldy i just tried the answer to the question you linked, but I still got a reduced sample.

Comment: @Peter If one of the answers below helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html). You should be able to set display for `max_rows` and `max_columns` like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
```

As noted in the docs, `None` sets the limit to be unlimited. Warning: you're going to fill your console up very quickly with large frames.

If you have particularly wide columns, you may need to tinker with `display.max_colwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation recently. I just needed a quick and easy way to just look at specific columns.

*Dependency Warning*: [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) must be installed.

This code includes the creation of a 61x61 data frame. A subprocess is opened. Pandocs converts the data frame from a LaTex format to a Markdown table format. `awk` is used to slice columns from the output. `less` paginates the output.

To examine, for example, to examine the 10th column, I executed the following in the terminal: `python print_pandas.py | awk '{ print $10 }' | less`

Change the `$10` value accordingly.

```
# contents of print_pandas.py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import shlex

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a large random data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.uniform(size=61) for _ in range(61)])

s = df.to_latex()
p = Popen(shlex.split('pandoc -f latex -t markdown'),
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
stdoutdata, _ = p.communicate(input=s.encode("utf-8"))
print(stdoutdata.decode("utf-8"))
```

[image: Output in terminal]