# write multiple pandas dataframe to the same txt file

Tags: pandas

I'm writing a summary and I need to write multiple `pandas` data frames to the same *txt* file. `.to_csv` method can only write one data frame to a file, so I tried the following code:

```
f = open('summary.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(df1))
f.write(str(df2))
f.write(str(df3))
f.close()
```

However, in the summary file, there were showed only parts of the data frames, most lines of each data frame were represented as `...`.

Comment: Relevant, and possibly even duplicate: [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
with open('summary.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df1.to_string())
    f.write(df2.to_string())
    f.write(df3.to_string())
```