# Python Idle column limitation

Tags: python, python-idle

I am trying to use Idle for working with some data and my problem is that when there are too many columns, some of them will be omitted after running and replaced with the dots. Is there a way to increase the limit set by Idle ide ? I have seen sentdex using Idle with up to 11 columns and all of them were presented, hence my question.

Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

What type are you printing? Some have a reduced representation that is produced by default by their `str` conversion to avoid flooding the terminal. You can get some of them to produce their full representation by applying `repr` to them and then printing the result.

This doesn't work for dataframes. They have their own adjustable row and column limits. See [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: pandas dataframe

Comment: IDLE does not set a limit on the length of lines any more than the standard REPL does.  It is the case that 'long' lines (say over 1000 chars) will slow down scrolling, but this does not seem to be your issue.