# How to get the full rows from a CSV you imported and cleaned on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, rows

So I had wrote a line of code which displays all values of a column. For example

```
tender_count = df.groupby(["Age Ranges"]).count()
```

when I gave it the `.head()` function it didn't display all the age ranges within the data. I want to know how I can display all the rows. If I am lacking in clarity I apologize in advance, this is my first post here and the other lines people posted to do this didn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you may want to read [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first.

I also believe that your question has already been asked and has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: I get 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_option'

Comment: Use this :

`import pandas as pd` 
  
`pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`