# Pandas displaying first 5 and last 5 results

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am currently trying to have my .csv imported in Python via Pandas. Some of the data properly shows up, but it's only the first 5 rows and then the last 5 rows.

I have about 3,000 rows that I want to show up, but cannot find a viable solution.

I am linking a screenshot and there is a copy of my code too. Thanks for the help! [Output of running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qteWL.png)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("ChicagoCrime2001.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Block', 'Primary Type'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) to display all results.

---

`pandas.DataFrame.to_string`

> *Render a DataFrame to a console-friendly tabular output.*

Answer (score 0):

try to use [set_options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Block', 'Primary Type'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior when printing pandas.DataFrame.

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

see [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe) for additional details.