# Python: Word Table to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, docx

I'm trying to put a Word Table into a DataFrame using the code below...

```
def writejsontable(theDataFrame):
    print(theDataFrame)
    print('-----------')

for block in iter_block_items(doc):
    tablestringarray = []
    if isinstance(block, Table):
        df = [['' for i in range(len(block.columns))] for j in range(len(block.rows))]
        for i, row in enumerate(block.rows):
            for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
                df[i][j] = block.cell(i,j).text
        writejsontable(df)
```

The code runs, but when I go to print the output it is...

`[['PERFORMANCE MEASURES', 'GO', 'NO-GO', 'N/A'], ['1. Put on Body Substance Isolation.', '', '', ''], ['2. Opened the airway used a manual maneuver.', '', '', '']]`

Is this how dataframes are normally printed? I've seen other examples where dataframes are printed in nice table like structures when you call a `print` on them. I'm not sure why i'm not getting that nice and neat table like structure when I'm calling a `print`. Any and all help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
def iter_block_items(parent):
    # Get parrent element
    if isinstance(parent, Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")
    # Get children in parent element
    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe Does this answer help at all?

Comment: df is a list of lists in your example not a dataframe: `df = [['' for i in range(len(block.columns))] for j in range(len(block.rows))]`

Comment: @Yo_Chris that makes sense. I'm trying to create an empty Dataframe with correct rows / columns numbers and then populate it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Bob I can take a look. Can you please provide and example for `block`

Comment: @Yo_Chris Basically it's just a `Table`. I'll throw the code in my post

Comment: @Bob does just creating a dataframe from the array work? `writejsontable(pd.DataFrame(df))`

Comment: @Yo_Chris that was embarrassingly simple! Throw that in an answer and i'd happily accept. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `df` is currently a list of lists and not a `pandas.DataFrame` You can convert the array `df` into a frame by using `pandas.DataFrame(df)`

```
# df = [['' for i in range(len(block.columns))] for j in range(len(block.rows))]
df= [['PERFORMANCE MEASURES', 'GO', 'NO-GO', 'N/A'],
     ['1. Put on Body Substance Isolation.', '', '', ''],
     ['2. Opened the airway used a manual maneuver.', '', '', '']]

writejsontable(pd.DataFrame(df))
```