# Limiting float value in for loop Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, floating-point, google-finance

I'm working on banking project, where my team asks me to limit all float values to .2 precision.

My dataSet.head()

[image: bank_stocks dataset]

Goal: To find max of all stocks comparatively

[image: My code & error i got]

My present output:

Bank Ticker
    BAC         54.900002
    C                 564.099976
    GS             247.919998
    JPM           70.080002
    MS              89.300003
    WFC          58.520000
    dtype: float64

My expected output:

Bank Ticker
    BAC         54.90
    C                 564.10
    GS             247.91
    JPM           70.08
    MS              89.30
    WFC          58.52
    dtype: float64

Please help me with this!

Comment: by limiting do you want to round or floor them ? `df.select_dtypes('float').round(2)` the answers here mainly use print formatting which won't change the actual values of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a wrong use of "{:.2f}" in your print statement, you should use `.format()` to format your float.

You can use `print("{:.2f}".format(some float))` to print a float with 2 decimals [as explained here](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/).

Comment: this works with normal range, but it's iterating through dataset, which cause trouble yielding output!

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work :

```
for tick in tickers:
  print(tick, "{:.2f}".format(bank_stocks[tick]['Close'].max()) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas.Series.round` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html)

I've got a toy `DataFrame` `df`:

```
l1        c1                           c2             
l2         a         b          c       a      b     c
0   0.066667  0.666667   6.666667  0.0002  0.002  0.02
1   0.133333  1.333333  13.333333  0.0004  0.004  0.04
2   0.200000  2.000000  20.000000  0.0006  0.006  0.06
3   0.266667  2.666667  26.666667  0.0008  0.008  0.08
```

```
df.xs('c', axis=1, level='l2').max().round(2)
```

Results into this:

```
l1
c1    26.67
c2     0.08
dtype: float64
```

I guess in your case

```
res = bank_stocks.xs('Close', axis=1, level='Stock Info').max().round(2)
```

would result into a `Series` `res` indexed by tickers with name `Bank Ticker` and desired values rounded up to 2 decimal places.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691921/10679134) you can then print it with

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(res)
```

Comment: am getting the following error on your code:
'float' object has no attribute 'round'

Comment: Could you provide your  `bank_stocks` DataFrame structure? e.g., using `bank_stocks.head(5)`. I mean, it's fine to use for loops, but pandas provides you with ways to do it much more efficiently

Comment: am sorry, but we can't upload here on comments right? i'll show on main question

Comment: @Thirumalaivasan, I've edited my answer, check it out. This (or something close to this) might have better performance than Python for loops

Comment: bank_stocks.xs(key='Close',axis=1,level='Stock Info').max().round(2)  i have used this code, which is really efficient, yes i agree yours its as great as it is.

Comment: @Thirumalaivasan, thank you, I've edited my answer again, liked your usage of `axis=1` instead of `.T`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a very advanced python programmer but I this should work:

```
{:.2f}.format(max())
```

to say the least, that will print out `564.099976` as `564.09`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, which is reliable, and without loop

```
bank_stocks.xs(key='Close',axis=1,level='Stock Info').max().round(2)
```

O(n)^2 is now O(n)

Answer (score -1):

This is not a clean solution but You can multiply the max stock price with 100, then do a floor division with 1 and then divide by 100.

This would solve your problems.

Comment: am not getting it, but the floor ain't working here