# python correlation matrix unstack and print all values

Tags: python-3.x, correlation

I'm trying to unstack a correlation matrix and print the values, I get something like this with truncation i.e. not all the values are displayed:

```
corr_pairs = corr_dict['corr'].unstack()
print(corr_pairs)

Assignment            Assignment                       1.000000
                      Country/Region                   0.242011
                      Interaction ID                   0.000000
                      Incident ID                      0.394528
                      Contact Last Name                0.667224
                                                         ...   
actual_end_plus_12hr  sImplementation on Time Scope   -0.209027
                      sImplementation on Time Met     -0.199003
                      sSuccess Rate Scope             -0.208897
                      sSuccess Rate Met               -0.208897
                      actual_end_plus_12hr             1.000000
Length: 4489, dtype: float64
```

Whereas I want all the values of the unstacked correlation matrix to be printed without any truncation. Something like this:

```
corr_pairs = corr_dict['corr'].unstack()
print(corr_pairs)

Assignment            Assignment                       1.000000
                      Country/Region                   0.242011
                      Interaction ID                   0.000000
                      Incident ID                      0.394528
                      Contact Last Name                0.667224
actual_end_plus_12hr  sImplementation on Time Scope   -0.209027
                      sImplementation on Time Met     -0.199003
                      sSuccess Rate Scope             -0.208897
                      sSuccess Rate Met               -0.208897
                      actual_end_plus_12hr             1.000000
actual_end_plus_12hr  sImplementation on Time Scope   -0.209027
                      sImplementation on Time Met     -0.199003
                      sSuccess Rate Scope             -0.208897
                      sSuccess Rate Met               -0.208897
                      actual_end_plus_12hr             1.000000
actual_end_plus_12hr  sImplementation on Time Scope   -0.209027
                      sImplementation on Time Met     -0.199003
                      sSuccess Rate Scope             -0.208897
                      sSuccess Rate Met               -0.208897
                      actual_end_plus_12hr             1.000000
actual_end_plus_12hr  sImplementation on Time Scope   -0.209027
                      sImplementation on Time Met     -0.199003
                      sSuccess Rate Scope             -0.208897
                      sSuccess Rate Met               -0.208897
                      actual_end_plus_12hr             1.000000
Length: 4489, dtype: float64
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The example was good enough, however I have included the desired output also.

Comment: No, it wasn't good enough.

Comment: It should have been reproducible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: In accordance with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400436/is-there-anything-to-do-with-users-with-a-profile-picture-clearly-endorsing-viol?noredirect=1#comment790330_400436), I am flagging this post. If you address the issue, I will retract the flag.