# Problem printing a CSV file with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csvreader

I have school project to submit by Sunday and I have a problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFns1.jpg), [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a24k.jpg)

```
import pandas as PD
DF=PD.read_csv('C:\New folder\Book4.csv')
print(DF)
```

This isn't the entire code but this part is the only issue. I have 4 CSV files in total and only this one is not printing the middle column for some reason. I had this issue before when I was trying to print second csv file but that just printed correctly after I added the third and fourth(this one) CSV file and this one got the problem
please help.

Comment: DataFrames are not printed completely by default. Normal behavior.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe

Comment: Try `print(df.to_string())`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have too many columns in this CSV.
You can set the number of columns to print:

```
 pd.set_option('display.max_columns',40)
```

The above code will increase the maximum to 40 columns

Comment: I only have 3 columns.

Comment: Then it could be a problem with the CSV itself. Post above an imge of this CSV