# Get output in a table in Jupyter note book - Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to get output in my jupyter notebook code in a table.
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

for x in range(1,1000):
    y=2*x+3
    print(x,y)
```

I get the output like below.

[image]

I need it in a table with column names "x" and "y". When I scroll down, the column names should be visible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, the cleanest way is to use pandas dataframe as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table=[]
for x in range(1,1000):
    y=2*x+3
    table.append([x,y])

df= pd.DataFrame(np.array(table_x),columns = ['x','y'])

print(df.head())
```

will give you

```
   x   y
0  1   5
1  2   7
2  3   9
3  4  11
4  5  13
```

Comment: Thank you. But  I get only first 5 values.

Comment: yes, print df.head will give you only the first 5 values.

To print all values you can use the solution described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe

Comment: Thank you. I will look in to that