# display dataframe with many columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has 100+ columns; so doing `head()` shown only a small portion of them.
I'd like to see the values of **all** of the columns for a sampling of the rows e.g. 10 rows.  Moreover I'd prefer for the values to be shown vertically (as to avoid needing to scroll horizontally through the table).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: thanks @mozway this partially answers my question; however in my case; I don't need to display the whole df (I have 1M rows); but do want to display all of the columns for a sampling of rows

Comment: Well, use `df.head()` as you mentioned in your question. You can also use `df.sample(10)` if you want 10 arbitrary rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired results by combining and tweaking answers from @mozway and @Vinay (thanks)

```py
# note that rows/cols will be transposed
pd.set_option('display.max_column', 20) 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df.T.head(df.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the  `display.max_column` option to None:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

See the [list of pandas options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

Edit:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    df.sample(10).T
```

Comment: Thanks; this works.  However, horizontal scrolling is not very convenient; if possible; I'd also would like an option to display columns vertically (in transposed format)

Answer (score 1):

@Neil,
If you want to display columns vertically (in transposed format), use -
df.T.head()

Comment: this doesn't quite work; `head` show only the first `5` columns (I want all)

Comment: If you want all columns then use only - df.T
If rows are more than 30 , then it will some rows , 
So first use - pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
then use df.T

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dtypes` that will show names and types of the columns:

```
 df.dtypes
```

It is short and very informative.