# Getting AttributeError: __enter__ when trying to print pandas dataframe with pd.set_option?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
if len(self.my_df)==865:
    with pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
        print(self.my_df)
```

According to [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe), that should be the correct syntax - and yet that line crashes with:

```
  File "myfile.py", line 1132, in my_function
    with pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: Thanks @richardec - pd.__version__='1.3.5'

Comment: Nice and new, good job. That's not the issue though. I figured it out; see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice in the post you linked, in the post you linked, they're using `pd.option_context`, but you're using `pd.set_option`. `with` statements call methods on the object they're passed such as `__enter__` and `__exit__`, but `pd.set_option` doesn't return an object that has those methods, while `pd.option_context` does. That's why you're seeing that error.

So just change your code to this:

```
if len(self.my_df)==865:
    with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
        print(self.my_df)
```