# Problem with uploading CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, uploading

I have some problem with uploding excel data in python.

**Excel**:

[image]

**Code** used to upload:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
#uploaded = files.upload()
import io
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['nodes.csv']),index_col=0)
print (df2)
```

**Result**:

[image]

Can you kindly help me?

Comment: what should the display be? you can use [`df.to_string()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923958/4541045) to produce a string output to paste here

Comment: I want to convert it to a numpy array.

Comment: What is your problem ? You say you have a problem, but don't describe what precisely this problem is. Anyway, I'm pretty sure it's an extension problem. Excel files have `.xls` or `.xlsx` extension, but not `.csv`, making the `read_csv()` method useless in your precise case

Comment: The received result and excel table are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to convert the imported data to a numpy array, you could do so by doing the following without using pandas:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt('nodes.csv', delimiter=',')
print(arr)
```

Check the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Comment: No error, but in the second column, I have 0.1. In the excel file instead of this value, we have 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a csv-file `file.csv`

```
0,0
2,0
4,0
1,1.732051
3,1.732051
```

then

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=0)
```

does produce

```
df =
        0.1
0          
2  0.000000
4  0.000000
1  1.732051
3  1.732051
```

Why is that: There are two `0`s in the first row and Pandas is *mangling the dupes* because the row is used for labels. The `0.1` isn't a number, it's a string (`print(df.columns)` will show `Index(['0.1'], dtype='object')`). If your file would look like

```
0,1
2,0
4,0
1,1.732051
3,1.732051
```

then this wouldn't happen, the output would look like

```
          1
0          
2  0.000000
4  0.000000
1  1.732051
3  1.732051
```

If your goal is NumPy array, then

```
arr = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None).values
```

leads to

```
array([[0.      , 0.      ],
       [2.      , 0.      ],
       [4.      , 0.      ],
       [1.      , 1.732051],
       [3.      , 1.732051]])
```