# Is there any way to read .pth(dataset) and turn them into csv?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I have a repo that provided a model architecture, but not pretrained model. it actually provides a .pth file but it's dataset inside the file, is there any way to make the dataset to csv?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*.pth* files saved with `toch.save()` are supposed to be binaries. using `torch.load()` you can get the dataset, and then save it again as a *.csv* with pandas for example

Comment: I'm using this to save it as csv,
`temp_data = torch.load('data/example.pth')
df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data)
df.to_csv("testfile",index=False)`
but it doesnt fully saving it, its writes ... on the matrix

Comment: What do you mean by it writes on the matrix?

Comment: ah what i mean is, do you know when array is way too long to print? that . . . .
is there any way to print it fully w/o that . . . .

Comment: I see, `pd.to_csv()` will save it to a file. If you want to print the full dataframe you can use ` pd.option_context()`, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691921/19492396

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for late reply, another problems make me forgot to vote for answer