# Display Pandas dataframe without vertical scrollbar in PyCharm's Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Using PyCharm 2022.1.4 to develop Jupyter notebooks, I would like to see complete Pandas dataframes without vertical scrollbars. Using the following code, the entire dataframe can be seen if scrolled. I would rather have all the lines shown at once. Thank you

```
from IPython.core.display_functions import display
import numpy as np
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, "expand_frame_repr", False):
    display(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 40))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing here worked in PyCharm? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: They don't seem to. Even the basic print's end up having scrollbars. A few of the suggestions are variants of the options I'm setting in option_context. My example's code works fine in Jupyter Lab. Seems like the vertical scrollbars are something PyCharm is adding, and maybe can't be removed? Haven't found an option in Settings either. Thank you