# Hitting a character limit in numpy while converting to array for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

TLDR - Seem to be running into a character limit in numpy? There's like some imaginary character limit I'm hitting while using numpy, showing in the Visual Studio Code debugger-
`SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 1, '<str_, len() = 67>'))`

Am I just using numpy wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

I currently have my data in this format:

```
row_table_data = [["Column1Header", "Column2Header", "Column3Header"], ["Column1DataA", "Column2DataA", "Column3DataA"], ["Column1DataB", "Column2DataB", "Column3DataB"], ["Column1DataC", "Column2DataC", "Column3DataC"]]
```

and I want my data to look like this using in pandas:

| Column1Header | Column2Header | Column3Header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column1DataA | Column2DataA | Column3DataA |
| Column1DataB | Column2DataB | Column3DataB |
| Column1DataC | Column2DataC | Column3DataC |

So my code currently is something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_headers = row_table_data[0]

wanted_table_data = []
for i in range(1, len(row_table_data)):
    wanted_table_data.append(row_table_data[i])

wanted_table_data = np.asarray(wanted_table_data)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(wanted_table_data, columns=column_headers)
print(dataframe)
```

This works fine if I print it:

```
  Column1Header Column2Header Column3Header
0  Column1DataA  Column2DataA  Column3DataA
1  Column1DataB  Column2DataB  Column3DataB
2  Column1DataC  Column2DataC  Column3DataC
```

But if I make one of the columns data with more text (usually over some char limit), it falls apart?

```
row_table_data = [["Column1Header", "Column2Header", "Column3Header"], ["Column1DataA", "Column2DataB Blah Blah Blah asdaasdasdsdasdasasass", "Column3DataA"], ["Column1DataB", "Column2DataB", "Column3DataB"], ["Column1DataC", "Column2DataC", "Column3DataC"]]
```

The np.asarray falls apart and my table looks like this:

```
   Column1Header  ... Column3Header
0  Column1DataA  ...  Column3DataA
1  Column1DataB  ...  Column3DataB
2  Column1DataC  ...  Column3DataC
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19124601/16768672)

Comment: Note: the actual data stored in the dataframe is correct, it is just not displaying it all because it is too long.

Comment: ay caramba. That makes complete sense. Thank you so much!