# Print all Columns in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to print all the columns in my file, but the result I get is this....

[image]

Do you know how I can show all the columns of my data frame?

the code is this:

```
file = pl.read_excel('1.xlsx')

file = file.drop_nulls()

print(file)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_cols.html#polars.Config.set_tbl_cols

Answer (score 6):

## You can use `polars.Config.set_tbl_cols` and `polars.DataFrame.width` to print dynamically all columns for any Polars DataFrame

E.g.,:

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,16))
print(df)
```

by default gives:

```
shape: (5, 16)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 ┆ … ┆ column_12 ┆ column_13 ┆ column_14 ┆ column_15 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆   ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.958006 ┆ 0.163983 ┆ 0.262214 ┆ 0.530242 ┆ … ┆ 0.576648  ┆ 0.396245  ┆ 0.295081  ┆ 0.210877  │
│ 0.46446  ┆ 0.743915 ┆ 0.560319 ┆ 0.033047 ┆ … ┆ 0.565604  ┆ 0.199547  ┆ 0.302649  ┆ 0.379063  │
│ 0.468403 ┆ 0.299781 ┆ 0.950776 ┆ 0.144336 ┆ … ┆ 0.820197  ┆ 0.809254  ┆ 0.659095  ┆ 0.235215  │
│ 0.995248 ┆ 0.07849  ┆ 0.964677 ┆ 0.620723 ┆ … ┆ 0.336031  ┆ 0.595888  ┆ 0.867185  ┆ 0.21454   │
│ 0.0762   ┆ 0.250534 ┆ 0.61255  ┆ 0.989831 ┆ … ┆ 0.463782  ┆ 0.539486  ┆ 0.440982  ┆ 0.741468  │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Whereas, the following (see [polars API docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_cols.html)) will print the whole dataframe (however "wide" it may be).

```py
with pl.Config(tbl_cols=-1):
    print(df)
```

Quote from the docs: `if n < 0 (eg: -1), display all columns`. The result is:

```
shape: (5, 16)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 ┆ column_4 ┆ column_5 ┆ column_6 ┆ column_7 ┆ column_8 ┆ column_9 ┆ column_10 ┆ column_11 ┆ column_12 ┆ column_13 ┆ column_14 ┆ column_15 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.958006 ┆ 0.163983 ┆ 0.262214 ┆ 0.530242 ┆ 0.338138 ┆ 0.748381 ┆ 0.929955 ┆ 0.646207 ┆ 0.793273 ┆ 0.996641 ┆ 0.198061  ┆ 0.89925   ┆ 0.576648  ┆ 0.396245  ┆ 0.295081  ┆ 0.210877  │
│ 0.46446  ┆ 0.743915 ┆ 0.560319 ┆ 0.033047 ┆ 0.61844  ┆ 0.086474 ┆ 0.627254 ┆ 0.30209  ┆ 0.863573 ┆ 0.345243 ┆ 0.437457  ┆ 0.443728  ┆ 0.565604  ┆ 0.199547  ┆ 0.302649  ┆ 0.379063  │
│ 0.468403 ┆ 0.299781 ┆ 0.950776 ┆ 0.144336 ┆ 0.670752 ┆ 0.197305 ┆ 0.444721 ┆ 0.02048  ┆ 0.907439 ┆ 0.726926 ┆ 0.209236  ┆ 0.713068  ┆ 0.820197  ┆ 0.809254  ┆ 0.659095  ┆ 0.235215  │
│ 0.995248 ┆ 0.07849  ┆ 0.964677 ┆ 0.620723 ┆ 0.104222 ┆ 0.952729 ┆ 0.160296 ┆ 0.532762 ┆ 0.839671 ┆ 0.333935 ┆ 0.386702  ┆ 0.178337  ┆ 0.336031  ┆ 0.595888  ┆ 0.867185  ┆ 0.21454   │
│ 0.0762   ┆ 0.250534 ┆ 0.61255  ┆ 0.989831 ┆ 0.870024 ┆ 0.306701 ┆ 0.466684 ┆ 0.404459 ┆ 0.53981  ┆ 0.37813  ┆ 0.175629  ┆ 0.281876  ┆ 0.463782  ┆ 0.539486  ┆ 0.440982  ┆ 0.741468  │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Looks like this changed recently; it's now `with pl.Config() as cfg: cfg.set_tbl_cols(df.width); print(df)`

Comment: @BallpointBen Are you sure? I added a link to the latest relevant polars API docs in my answer with a new a edit just now. As far as I can tell both are valid. I think the difference is just if the dataframe were to be defined _within_ the `with` block, then, it would necessarily not be available to provide the width as a direct parameter to `pl.Config`.

Comment: `pl.Config(x=1) # TypeError: Config() takes no arguments`

Comment: Well for one did you look at the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_cols.html), though? They recommend explicitly both syntax options. And when I run `with pl.Config(x=10): print(df);` I get `AttributeError: \`Config\` has no option 'set_x'` and from `pl.__version__` I am running v0.19.5. Also, see `help(pl.Config)` - it definitely takes arguments, there is an extensive documented series of examples.

Comment: Whoops, it's my polars that was out of date. Apologies. (And TIL that `poetry update` does not, in fact, update.)

Comment: I changed the value to -1 in the answer: `pl.Config(tbl_cols=-1)` . The current stable version 0.20 accepts a negative number to show **all** columns. So it is not necessary to tell it how many columns it should print, if it should print all. (it should know how many there are by itself, shouldn't it?)