# Why python doesn't print complete text when typing through a range or multiple items?

Tags: python, text, printing

I am trying to extract data from GSC and it has multiple URLs (in this case sitemaps). When I try to type individual URL using:
`print(site_map_df.loc[1,'path']` it prints the complete URL like:

[image: Single Path Result]

However, when I try to print in bulk it ends up truncating the URLs and append them with ...

`print(site_map_df['path'])`
results in following:
[image: Multiple Selection Result]

Can anyone of you kind people please help me with it? How to avoid these ...s.

Thanks and Regards

I tried multiple print types and was expecting atleast one of them will remove these dots.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question includes a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Post text/code, not images, please.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to print `df["column_name"]`, it is interpreted as "print [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object". What I see you want is, to print not the Series object representation, but only the values it contains:

```
print(site_map_df['path'].values)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard behavior when you print a Series. You probably want to print the value instead.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['https://this.is.a.very.long.url.blablablablablablablablablalblablablablablalbalb.com'],
    'B':['ww.google.com']
    })

print('SERIES', df['A'])
print('VALUE', df['A'].values[0])
```

Which gives:

```
SERIES 0    https://this.is.a.very.long.url.blablablablabl...
Name: A, dtype: object
VALUE https://this.is.a.very.long.url.blablablablablablablablablalblablablablablalbalb.com
```

To change the default behavior, you need to change the context. For that, please check the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html and  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html and this thread [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe/37347783#37347783)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the framework / module you're using, so maybe some others know better, but you could just iterate through site_map_df.loc like

```
for i in range(url_count):
  print(site_map_df[i, "path"]
```

Maybe you should include some information in your question about which module you are using, how you obtained the site_map_df list and what type/class it is. That's always helpful. Maybe show your piece of source code where you generated the list. Also try checking the documentation for how theses lists work and what methods there are.