# Jupyter Notebook output in vscode truncates and will not scroll

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a particular notebook for which truncated outputs won't scroll and I'm unable to see the complete output. In the image below I'm showing what the outputs look like for two different notebooks using the same python kernel. In the notebook with the problem, I don't get this option "Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings..."

It seems like this is only the case for pandas objects, because if I convert a series .tolist() then the output will scroll.

[image: Two Notebooks comparing the problem]

Converting .tolist() doesn't help when trying to view dataframe info:

[truncated .info() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VodGG.png)

I have tried editing the various Notebook Layout Settings:

- Notebook › Output: Text Line Limit is set to 30 (I have tried 0 and larger #'s)
- Notebook › Output: Scrolling is unchecked (I've tried checking it)

I have also tried rerunning and reinstalling vscode.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19124601/11107541 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a apple/oranges situation. The df1.columns property on a dataframe is not a Dataframe nor a Series, and so is not the df1.columns.to_list().

wrapping it in Display(df1.columns) or even display(Markdown(df1.columns)) won't help.

I would do

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown   

for col in bookit_items.columns.to_list():
    display(Markdown(f"* {col}"))
```

to display all column names in a list.