# Python: How to display a dataframe using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter. I have tried a few widgets provided by Tkinter but cannot find a suitable way to display a dataframe.

I tried `Tkinter.Text`. I used `update()` instead of `mainloop()` because I would like to update `df` and display again. `mainloop()` will block my program. The problem with this approach is that when the `df` gets big in size, it cannot be displayed fully.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk() 
t1 = Tkinter.Text(root) 
t1.pack()
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(900,2),columns=list('AB')) 
t1.insert('end', df) 

root.update()
```

I also tried `Tkinter.Lablel`. It actually insert entries of the `df` one by one, which is very slow.

```
from Tkinter import *
for i in range(900):
    for j in range(4):
        l = Label(text='%d.%d' % (i, j), relief=RIDGE)
        l.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
mainloop()
```

So what is the easiest way to display a data frame(no need for editing)? To be specific, it should more or less look like an excel spread sheet with scrollbars, and allow the displayed `df` to be updated and display again. Also, it should not take too long if `df` has hundreds of rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question sounds ok, I'd recommend to summarize your needs in the question in the bottom (the word "nicely" is too vague). Best regards.

Comment: @YakovL thanks for the advice. I added my needs at the end of the question.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found [pandas-qt](https://github.com/datalyze-solutions/pandas-qt/blob/master/examples/BasicExample.py) easy to use and the display is very fast.

There are some alternative solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix)