# Viewing Pandas df in Eclipse on a Separate Window

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas

I am trying to see how pandas dataframes look like without needing to use print. Can I do that with eclipse? This relatively older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix) has a solution, but I thought for Eclipse there should exist a more convinient way of checking variable values (including the dataframes).