# Creating pandas GUI click on a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface

I am building a program for my company that happens to match names.  I created a function that takes in as input the users name, address, state and zip, internally it runs a query on mysql database, and runs a regex matching and jaro winkler matching to return a list of potential matches.  It works as it should.  My problem is, if a dataframe is returned with multiple rows, i want the user to be able to click on a row and internally it returns information about that person to the user.  Is there any gui that allows me to do this in python?  Thank you

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python / Pandas - GUI for viewing a DataFrame or Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix)