# Semi-Interactive Pandas Dataframe in a GUI

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, pyqt, interactive

There are a number of excellent answers to this question [GUIs for displaying dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix), but what I'm looking to do is a bit more advanced.

I'd like to display a dataframe, but have a couple of the columns be interactive where the user can manually overwrite values (and the rest be static).  It would be useful to have "total" rows that change with the overwritten values and eventually have some interactive buttons around the dataframe for loading and clearing data.

[QTPandas](https://github.com/draperjames/qtpandas/issues) looks promising, but appears to be dead as it is build off of a really old version of Pandas (0.17.1).  Can this be done in QT?  Is something else better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a GUI in itself, [XLWings](https://www.xlwings.org/) leveraged Excel as a GUI and makes pandas dataframes interactive for users and was our library of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I love Rstudio as my IDE as I can not only view all objects created but I can also edit data in the IDE itself. There are many other great features too.
And you can use R Studio for Python coding too (using reticulate package).

Spyder too gives this feature of viewing or editing the data frame.

However, if you're looking for a **dedicated GUI with drag & drop features**, you can use **Pandas GUI**.
Features of [pandasgui](https://pypi.org/project/pandasgui/#history) are:

- View DataFrames and Series (with MultiIndex support)
- Interactive plotting
- Filtering
- Statistical summary
- Data editing and copy / paste
- Import CSV files with drag & drop Search toolbar

It's first version was released in Mar 2019 & still developing. As of date, you can't use it in Colab