# Is it possible to manipulate data from csv without the need for producing a new csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to import and manipulate data from csv, but I always need to save to xlsx or so to see the changes. Is there a way to see 'live changes' as if I am already using Excel?

PS using pandas

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, build your own output script that keeps refreshing from an in-memory structure. Something like this: https://github.com/kristianperkins/x_x Alternatively you could use something like jupyter notebook to view the data structure in real time

Comment: @BoboDarph Thank. Could creating an excel macro or visual basic be more effective in that case as well?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The data structure must be accessible to that script you plan to write. There are cheaper ways to visualise a pandas dataframe. Something like this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using pandas. This lib creates copy of your .csv / .xls file and stores it in RAM. So all changes are applied to file stored in you memory not on disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could an excel macro or visual basic do this task?

Comment: Seems that online showing changes in some dashboard or in jupyter notebook will be more common. So you may send new data to dash and for some cases build plots. See examples here: https://plot.ly/pandas/dashboard/