# Displaying Data in Python GUI

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL database and in python 3.6+ I would like to view data form said database in a window. for example one column multi rows. Drawing a blank at the moment.

I am also using PyQt5 but i do not use the designer. I can how ever create the database and tables and query this and print to the python console. Dont want this I need to display the information on a GUI... Any help with serious answers is most welcome as I am mystified at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has already been answered here: 
[Python / Pandas - GUI for viewing a DataFrame or Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636024/python-pandas-gui-for-viewing-a-dataframe-or-matrix)

please review the answer provided by bluenote10 as he also shares his sourcecode on Github: https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI

Comment: I do not want to use PANDAS I just want to populate a QList or whatever with data from my database that is it. Should this not be a simple operation?

Comment: check the thread lower, it has a pycharm solution that does not directly rely on pandas. not sure how you want to quickly implement the dataframe and why importing pandas would be so bad?

Comment: Never used it and need a very quick way just to take the data from my database and view in my GUI. Unless this is the only way of doing it that is. I have a very tight time frame as in friday tea time!!