# "pip uninstall jupyter" does not work but, "which jupyter" returns a valid path

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I am trying to uninstall jupyter.

`pip uninstall jupyter`, it gives me this error:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed
```

but `which jupyter` says

```
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

I tried using `pip install pip-autoremove` and then `pip-autoremove jupyter -y` but that gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip-autoremove", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 109, in main
    autoremove(args, yes=opts.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 21, in autoremove
    dead = list_dead(names)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 28, in list_dead
    start = set(map(get_distribution, names))
  File "/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 562, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 436, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 981, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 867, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jupyter' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

---

**Edit**

updating question to include output of `pip list`

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
jupyter-client (5.1.0)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.3.0)
```

Comment: can you check `pip list` ? or `pip list | grep jupyter` does that returns any results.

Comment: yes @bhansa  DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
jupyter-client (5.1.0)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.3.0)

Comment: Can you try `pip uninstall jupyter-*` ?

Comment: did you find a solution? i face the same problem

Comment: nope .. never worked

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912244/7395911). Have a look and see if it solves your question or perhaps clarify the diferences from it.

In the meantime, have a look at a tip I can give you below.

---

Make use of [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) if possible, it will save you from future headaches like this.

Run `pip install virtualenv`.

Then in your project folder, or any desired folder call `virtualenv venv`.

I will create a **virtual environment** where you will have no packages installed or maybe just a few.

To use the newly created **virtualenv** just execute `source venv/bin/activate`.

Now run `pip freeze` and it will show you a clean package list.

Install all you **requirements** the same way as usual, I'll assume you know how to do it.

Then run your **jupyter** project.

Comment: The question was about _uninstalling_ jupyter.

Comment: @GinoMempin True, I don't remember why, but i thought that this could help solve the problem. Despite this, I'll be editing my answer asap to match the question.