# How to Completely uninstall jupyter

Tags: pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am unable to open jupyter notebook `.ipynb` files (i can open jupyter notebook, but when i click on a `.ipynb` it exits with unkown error)
Therefore i want to completely get rid of jupyter and ipython.

I deinstalled jupyter and ipython with `sudo pip uninstall`, also with `pip2` and `pip3`, but still i am able to find jupyter at `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` and i am also able to start it with `jupyter`.

If i now reinstall jupyter with pip, i get the same errors as before, so i guess it always starts the same that i still installed.

So how can i deinstall this? just remove the binary?

Edit1:
i am using `python 2.7` and `Ubuntu 16.04` if that matters

Edit2:
i got basically the same problem as this [pip uninstall jupyter does not work but which jupyter returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372877/pip-uninstall-jupyter-does-not-work-but-which-jupyter-returns)

Edit3:
The complete error output when i try to open a jupyter-notebook:

```
[E 14:59:58.222 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1523883598008 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1523883598008', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,en-US;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Xsrftoken': '2|ef5ec4f7|efb210b548db14e572dec5fa47cd9d4c|1523879395', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8888/notebooks/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb', 'Cookie': '_xsrf=2|ef5ec4f7|efb210b548db14e572dec5fa47cd9d4c|1523879395; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1523883578|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjJhYjc1MjI4Y2UwNDBlMDg1ZGJkN2QyMTkzZmM5ZGU=|c9400d948f07d89cf10b581a1251394138f0f7180395bdcffd5df47bd396c189"'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1512, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 418, in get
        model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 378, in _notebook_model
        self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 502, in mark_trusted_cells
        trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 438, in check_signature
        signature = self.compute_signature(nb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 413, in compute_signature
        hmac = HMAC(self.secret, digestmod=self.digestmod)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
        return self.get(obj, cls)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
        value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 387, in _secret_default
        self._write_secret_file(secret)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 397, in _write_secret_file
        with io.open(self.secret_file, 'wb') as f:
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/gustav/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret'
[W 14:59:58.223 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 14:59:58.223 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "de-DE,en-US;q=0.5", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|ef5ec4f7|efb210b548db14e572dec5fa47cd9d4c|1523879395", 
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
      "Host": "localhost:8888", 
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb", 
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|ef5ec4f7|efb210b548db14e572dec5fa47cd9d4c|1523879395; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1523883578|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjJhYjc1MjI4Y2UwNDBlMDg1ZGJkN2QyMTkzZmM5ZGU=|c9400d948f07d89cf10b581a1251394138f0f7180395bdcffd5df47bd396c189\""
    }
[E 14:59:58.223 NotebookApp] 500 GET /api/contents/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1523883598008 (127.0.0.1) 37.67ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/workspace/Mobile_Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb
```

Comment: i know conda and i knrow virstual envs, but my problem is as stated and i want to get rid of it :D

Comment: You have a permissions issue. Hopefully it's just due to the `/home/gustav/.local/share/jupyter` directory not existing, cuz that's easy to fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fixing the `jupyter` error

You have a permissions issue:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/gustav/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret'
```

Uninstalling is not going to help, at least not directly. You might be able to fix it by entering this command in a terminal:

```
mkdir -p ${HOME}/.local/share/jupyter
```

This will fix the error if it was due to the `.local/share/jupyter` directory not existing.

## Completely uninstalling `jupyter`

If you can't fix the permission issue, here's the simplest set of commands for nuking `jupyter` from space:

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove jupyter -y
```

From a little bit of testing I just did, you might also have to run at the end:

```
pip-autoremove jupyter-core -y
```

## Opening `.ipynb` files with a doubleclick

You can't open `.ipynb` with just vanilla Jupyter by double clicking. This is by design (also arguably a design flaw, but eh). You can add this functionality with the [nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen) project.

To install on Ubuntu, just run the following in a terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install nbopen
python3 -m nbopen.install_xdg
```

I haven't tested this though since I'm not running Linux.

## How to open `.ipynb` files the "normal" way

You can't open `.ipynb` with just vanilla Jupyter by double clicking. This is by design (also arguably a design flaw, but eh).

Instead, you have to open files in the Jupyter file manager, which you run like this:

1. Open a new terminal window (in Ubuntu you can just enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Start up the notebook server by running `jupyter notebook`
3. This should automatically open a new window in your internet browser that's pointing to the Jupyter file manager. If it doesn't, there'll be a line in your terminal that says something like

   ```
   Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time, to login with a token:
   ```

   In that case, just copy the following URL into the address bar of a browser window and hit enter.
4. You should now have a browser window showing the Jupyter file manager. Use the file manager to navigate to the `.ipynb` you want to open, and then just click on it.

Admittedly a bit convoluted, especially at first. I believe the reason Jupyter is set up this way goes back to its server-based architecture, and the fact that the design team wanted it to be easily/seamlessly deployed on remote computers.