# How do you completely uninstall jupyter notebook and jupyterlab from a mac when standard uninstall commands have no effect?

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This has been asked many times - but I cannot for the life of me get rid of jupyter notebook/jupyterlab. I want to not be able to run a jupyter notebebook so that I can re-install everything.

I have tried the simple
`pip uninstall jupyterlab` `pip uninstall notebook` `pip uninstall jupyter` also with pip3 options

I have tried

```
$ pip3 install pip-autoremove
$ pip-autoremove jupyter -y
```

and changed pip3 for pip in case that made a difference.

I have followed what has been suggested with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912244/2613271)

The output to `which jupyter` is `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`.  I tried `sudo /usr/local/bin/python -m pip uninstall jupyter` following the comment answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33052232/2613271).

Whenever I try remove it I just get `Skipping jupyter as it is not installed.` errors, yet if you run `jupyter notebook` it runs, and `which jupyter` continues to return a result.

It was suggested that I re-install Python3, but Jupyter Notebook is running Python2 (on a mac, so can't get rid of that), and I can't uninstall Python3 either following any instructions I can find.

Is there any way to get rid of this program from a mac when all the above fail to do anything?

Far as I know it was installed with pip, but I also checked if it was installed through conda (conda not recognised as a command)

I am running macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6.  Python versions are

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```