# Jupyter Notebook Stopped Showing All Folders/ Files in Browser View

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am assisting a colleague who's Jupyter Notebook is not showing folders in the browser view.  It previously did show them, and no Python updates were performed, but he can not access them now.  This is part of an Anacoda build in Windows 10.  We have uninstalled Anaconda and re-installed without success.  We then uninstalled Jupyter specific packages following the recommendations of Rahul Bharadwaj [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter) with no luck.  We also tried launching Jupyter as Administrator but did not have any success.  Below are applicable versions in his Python 3 environment.  Any advice or direction would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after troubleshooting this for my colleague I migrated to Microsoft One-Drive and all of my folders disappeared.  I referenced back to other information that I had discovered during troubleshooting.  It turns out, that was the problem.  The folders previously in Documents had moved to One-Drive/Documents.