# Why is pipenv still using the global jupyter (/usr/bin/python3) and not encapsulated on its own environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

I created a **test** folder and then did `pipenv install` inside this test folder.

After that, I ran `pipenv shell` to activate my new environment.

So far so good...

And then I ran `pip freeze`

[image: result of pip freeze command]

There's no `jupyter` in this just created virtual machine, but if I type `jupyter notebook`, it opens jupyter o_O

On the jupyter notebook I ran `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` to check if the environment is fine, but it's actually running my global environment outside the pipenv. Although, it's running the correct Python on `!which python` command.

[image: jupyter notebook inside the pipenv environment]

Can anyone please tell me what I have to do to have a `pipenv` environment isolated (encapsulated) to work on different projects?

Comment: The python in the virtualenv is just a symlink to the /usr/bin/python (or whichever python you used to create it). If you deactivate the virtual env, then do `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip freeze`, do you see jupyter listed? I'm guessing your global python3 already has jupyter.

Comment: Hello, @GinoMempin =) Yes, I have jupyter installed on global environment, not it the brand new environment thou. This is what is intriguing me =/ There's a bunch of packages installed on global, and that's reason why I'm using pipenv to isolate environments for new projects. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, the typical workflow with `pipenv` and installing packages is:

1. Setup system-wide python and virtual environment module (i.e. `pipenv`)
2. Create your project folder (i.e. `test`)
3. Create a virtual environment there (i.e. `pipenv shell` or `pipenv install`)

   - You can pass in a specific python version (important if you have multiple installed)
   - With `pipenv`, pass [`--python=/path/to/python3`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv-and-other-python-distributions)
4. Install your packages (i.e. `pipenv install jupyter`)

Now for `jupyter`. When you install it, it adds a `bin/jupyter` executable. Since you already have it installed with your system-wide python, then it also becomes available system-wide (even inside a `pipenv shell`).

```
~$ python3.8 -m pip install jupyter
...
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.0)

~$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter

~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Invoking `jupyter` should find it in `/usr/local/bin`. Inside a `pipenv shell`, it does not block you from accessing system-wide `bin` things (because that would be annoying). So inside a `pipenv shell`, your `jupyter` installation is still available:

```
TEMP$ pipenv shell

(TEMP) TEMP$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.2.4
setuptools 50.3.2
wheel      0.35.1

(TEMP) TEMP$ echo $PATH
/Users/me/.venvs/TEMP-S6DFgeUE/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

(TEMP) TEMP$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter

(TEMP) TEMP$ jupyter --version   # Can be invoked here even if not in pip list
```

What the `pipenv shell` does is prepend another `/bin` folder at the front of your `$PATH`, so packages you install inside this env and add `bin` things will be accessible. Invoking them should find it first from the virtual environment. What happened to you is that invoking `jupyter` did not find it inside the virtual environment's `bin` (`/Users/me/.venvs/TEMP-S6DFgeUE/bin`), but in the system-side bin (`/usr/local/bin`). That is *why* even without installing `jupyter` in your virtual environment, it is still accessible.

This generally applies to packages that install `bin` things.

Now, what to do. As I mentioned at the start, you should (as much as possible) avoid installing things in the system-wide python. Only install things (as much as possible) inside a virtual environment.

So, for your case, start with installing `jupyter` inside your virtual environment:

```
(TEMP) TEMP$ pipenv install jupyter
Installing jupyter...
...

(TEMP) TEMP$ which jupyter
/Users/me/.venvs/TEMP-S6DFgeUE/bin/jupyter

(TEMP) TEMP$ jupyter --version  # Check that it works

(TEMP) TEMP$ ls $(pipenv --venv)/lib/python3.8/site-packages | grep jupyter
jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info
jupyter.py
jupyter_client
jupyter_client-6.1.7.dist-info
jupyter_console
jupyter_console-6.2.0.dist-info
jupyter_core
jupyter_core-4.7.0.dist-info
jupyterlab_pygments
jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2.dist-info
```

When you install it, invoking `jupyter` should now find it from the virtual environment `bin`. It should also add the `jupyter` things in the virtual environment's site-packages folder.

To confirm that your jupyter in your virtual environment is working, I **highly recommend** uninstalling the system-wide jupyter. Note that it's not enough to just do `pip uninstall jupyter`, you need to uninstall it completely to remove the `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` (see: [How to uninstall jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter)):

```
python3.8 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat
```

Then go back to your `pipenv shell`, and confirm that you *only* have `jupyter` inside your virtual environment:

```
~$ jupyter --version
-bash: jupyter: command not found

~$ cd TEMP
TEMP$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
...

(TEMP) TEMP$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.5
qtconsole        : 5.0.1
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5

(TEMP) TEMP$ which jupyter
/Users/me/.venvs/TEMP-S6DFgeUE/bin/jupyter
```