# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine

I am using a windows machine to start Jupyter notebook server on a virtual Ubuntu 16.04. I expect a URL as an output which I can paste in internet browser and run a .ipynb file. `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0`  is producing the following error after I have upgraded Python to 3.7.

*(Earlier to upgradation, the jupyter notebook was working fine)

```
pkj_admin@ip-50-60-0-75:~$  jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue. I solved it using:

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue with jupyter notebook. It says `jupyter_core` not found with current installation packages. It is messed up with paths.

> `jupyter_core` might be installed locally but it is looking at root or sys python version. Try to uninstall there and reinstall `jupyter`.

```
>> python -m pip uninstall jupyter-core;python -m pip uninstall jupyter;

# inside conda env or similar env
>> pip uninstall jupyter
>> pip install jupyter
```

Ref: [How to remove jupyter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter)

Answer (score 0):

While you really should fix whatever dependency problem you have, I also found that you can just do `python -m jupyter notebook` as a quick workaround.