# How to remove Jupyter + all its components completely (As if it never existed)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

After I totally messed up my base (root) environment and the Jupyter installation within, I want to install it from scratch. To do so, I need to remove it entirely from my system. I tried the solutions recommended in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter) but the `jupyter` command would not stop working and still returned an output.

How do I successfully eliminate Jupyter from my system (Linux) and I mean everything:

- Jupyter
- Jupyter Lab
- All its dependencies
- All its files, cached/uncached
- All installed extensions
- All configurations
- All kernels
- All data directories
- All paths and directories
- IPython included

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around, here is my final solution on top of the solutions proposed in the [mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter). Here are the steps:

0. Uninstall Jupyter and its dependencies:

```
pip uninstall jupyter jupyterlab
pip uninstall jupyter_core ipython ipykernel ipywidgets jupyter_client jupyterlab nbclient nbconvert nbformat notebook qtconsole traitlets
```

1. Remove Jupyter Configurations:

```
rm -rf ~/.jupyter
```

2. Remove Jupyter paths:

2.1. Run `jupyter --paths`

2.2. Remove all paths listed with:

```
rm -rf <path>
```

3. Remove Jupyter Cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/jupyter
```

4. Remove IPython configs:

```
rm -rf ~/.ipython
```

5. Verify removal:

```
jupyter --version
```

If you get "Not found error", then Jupyter is removed from your system like it never existed.