# How can I 'clean up' a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

If I want to keep my venv as clean as possible how can I clean up the stuff I don't need? Let me lay out an example...

Say I try a bunch of new modules...

```
pip install foo
pip install bar
pip install foobar
pip install foobarfoo
```

and these modules have some requirements of their own, etc. later I decide on which one I want to use, but then I have a huge list of stuff in my requirement.txt and I can't remember what I need and what I don't, what depends on what, etc.

How can I keep it clean and lean?

Comment: the whole point is I am not sure of what I need based on dependencies. Of course I could delete the whole thing, let my processes fail and install as I go, but I am looking for an easier way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27713702/1547004) answer may be just what you need.

> You can install and use the [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove) utility to remove a package
>   plus unused dependencies.
>
> ```
> # install pip-autoremove 
> pip install pip-autoremove
> # remove "somepackage" plus its dependencies: 
> pip-autoremove somepackage -y
> ```

Comment: Don't forget to remove pip-autoremove when done! :->

Comment: Why would I remove pip autoremove when I am done instead of just leaving it there for future use?

Comment: I wonder if pip uninstall wouldn't do... When I'm removing with pip-autoremove, there are some dependencies which pip-autoremove cannot deal with (it seems that the order of deleting is important) while pip uninstall works fine.

Comment: @fanny pip uninstall doesn't remove any dependencies at all.

Answer (score 54):

To uninstall every package (including dependencies) you can freeze the requirements and then pass them to `pip uninstall`:

```
pip freeze > to-uninstall.txt
pip uninstall -r to-uninstall.txt
```

Comment: That is the best thing I have seen all week. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a great solution. However, for larger virtual environments it can be annoying to have to confirm the removal of each package.

In that event, I'd recommend using:  `pip uninstall -y -r  to-uninstall.txt` which bypasses the prompt

Answer (score 19):

The following works for me (can be executed from any Python 3.6 `virtualenv`):

```bash
virtualenv --clear your-env-name
```

Where `your-env-name` could be:

- Path to the virtual environment (relative from current directory or absolute)
- Or if you use `virtualenv-wrapper`, just the name of the environment

If that doesn't work for you somehow, there's is this less convenient one-liner:

```bash
pip freeze | while read p; do pip uninstall -y "$p"; done
```

Comment: "Delete the contents of the environment directory if it already exists, before environment creation."

Comment: that didn't work for me...

Comment: Error: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: [path to the venv]

Comment: @Liker777: I just checked. It still works fine on Python 3.10. What did you do? System, full command?

Answer (score 10):

Following the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61080118/15450772) from @Steve Rossiter and @James Rocker
one could also do a trivial modification and avoid generating a temp file in a one-liner like:

```
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

(I wanted to post this as a comment on the answer, but I don't have enough reputation for that.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)'s `pip-sync` functionality to keep your environment clean.

From [pip-tools' documentation](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools):

> Now that you have a requirements.txt, you can use `pip-sync` to update your virtual environment to reflect exactly what's in there. This will install/upgrade/uninstall everything necessary to match the requirements.txt contents.

Just install pip-tools and call the pip-sync command:

```sh
pip install pip-tools
pip-sync requirements.txt
```

(side note: pip-tools is also great to manage you dependency versions to make your builds predictable and deterministic; see [pip-tools' documentation](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) for more information)

Answer (score 7):

To slightly improve on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61080118/15356405)

Use pip but add -y to avoid prompts for every library.

Don't forget to remove the file "to_uninstall.txt" when done!

```
pip freeze > to_uninstall.txt
pip uninstall -y -r to_uninstall.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

(Inspired by [Tripp Kinetics' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70157541/2745495))

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a one-liner for this:

```
pip list | tail +3 | cut -f1 -d\  | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Afterwards, you probably would want to:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

To get `pip` back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to uninstall all packages easily

```
pip uninstall -y $(pip freeze)
```

Answer (score -1):

`pip uninstall` followed by one or more package names will remove the packages from the virtual environment.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)