# How can I tell which installed packages my Python project is not using?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been working on a project for a while now and have installed various packages over the time I've worked with it, some of which I suspect are no longer required to run the code, and I don't want to include them in the `requirements.txt`.  Is there any way to know which installed packages in my venv are either imported somewhere in my Python project or are a dependency of a package that is imported, so that I can remove the unused packages from the `requirements.txt`?

- My question is related to [How can I 'clean up' a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075812/how-can-i-clean-up-a-virtualenv) but is not the same, because in that case the OP knew which top-level package (of several he installed) he wanted to keep, and was trying to figure out how to uninstall the others along with their dependencies, while in my case I don't even know which top-level packages I need.
- My question is similar to [this one regarding the R programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415614/how-can-i-tell-which-packages-i-am-not-using-in-my-r-script).

Comment: Just comment out the import and see whether the program runs smoothly. If it does, the import was not necessary. And as a general rule: Only import packages you use at the moment you start using them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237244/4115031): use [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) to get a list of the top-level packages actually required by a project:

`pip install pipreqs` and then `pipreqs .` (from the top level of your project).