# Pip uninstall Scrapy with all its dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I had installed Scrapy with `pip install scrapy`. It also install all its requirement packages `Installing collected packages: zope.interface, Twisted, six, cssselect, w3lib, parsel, pycparser, cffi, pyasn1, idna, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, attrs, pyasn1-modules, service-identity, queuelib, PyDispatcher, scrapy`. So, is it possible to uninstall scrapy and all its requirement packages with a terminal command?

Comment: bwv549 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915998/does-uninstalling-a-package-with-pip-also-removes-the-dependent-packages suggested to install `pip-autoremove`. Check if it works or not.

Comment: I think it solves my problem. Thank

Comment: So, `pip-autoremove` worked?

Comment: I try and it works, but I don't know why @Bibhas comment said that the package broke. I used this command for python3.

Comment: Cool! Nice that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit contrived but you can use something like this

```
for p in `pip show scrapy | grep 'Requires:' | tr ',' ' ' | cut -d " " -f2-`;
do
    pip uninstall $p;
done;
```

Comment: I try it, but some of the packages do not uninstall. Look like it can only detect some of the packages only.

Answer (score 0):

pip-autoremove is a Python package that **removes packages and all its dependencies**:

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove <package> -y
```

Answer (score -1):

`pip uninstall` currently doesn't support removing the dependencies. You can manually go to the folder where scrapy is installed and delete it. For example: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy`.

For example if it is at `'/PATH/TO/SCRAPY'`, run this command on the terminal:

`sudo rm -rf /PATH/TO/SCRAPY`

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. What I want is a command that can uninstall scrapy and all its requirement package like zope.interface, Twisted and others.